# Overriding !important style

Tags: javascript, css

Title pretty much sums it up.

The external style sheet has the following code:

```css
td.EvenRow a {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I have tried using:

```
element.style.display = "inline";
```

and

```
element.style.display = "inline !important";
```

but neither works. Is it possible to override an !important style using javascript.

This is for a greasemonkey extension, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this it to add the style as a new CSS declaration with the '!important' suffix. The easiest way to do this is to append a new <style> element to the head of document:

```
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
    var styleElement = document.getElementById('styles_js');
    if (!styleElement) {
        styleElement = document.createElement('style');
        styleElement.type = 'text/css';
        styleElement.id = 'styles_js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
    }
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}

addNewStyle('td.EvenRow a {display:inline !important;}')
```

The rules added with the above method will (if you use the !important suffix) override other previously set styling. If you're not using the suffix then make sure to take concepts like '[specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)' into account.

Comment: This could be replaced by a one-liner. See below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style-using-javascript/1577204#1577204

Comment: How are you gonna find the selector that actually triggers the style? I think this requires parsing all stylesheets, which is a pretty tough job.

Comment: the bad is sometimes it cannot override '!important', the better is set directly in element.

Answer (score 441):

There are a couple of simple one-liners you can use to do this.

1. Set a  "style" *attribute* on the element:

```
element.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline !important');
```

or...

2. Modify the `cssText` property of the `style` object:

```
element.style.cssText = 'display:inline !important';
```

Either will do the job.

===

I've written a jQuery plugin called "important" to manipulate `!important` rules in elements, : http://github.com/premasagar/important

===

Edit:
As shared in the comments, the standard CSSOM interface (the API for JavaScript to interact with CSS) provides the [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method:

```
element.style.setProperty(propertyName, value, priority);
```

E.g:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', 'important');
```

Comment: I think that using cssText is simpler then adding a `style` tag.

Comment: @Guss - The first example I gave is for a `style` attribute, not a tag/element.

Comment: Yes, I know- I compared your answer to @J-P's selected one, and I tried to say that I think your's is better.

Comment: To prevent overriding other properties, you man want to use `element.style.cssText += ';display:inline !important;';`

Comment: See also the CSSOM standard, [style.setProperty(property, value, priority)](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setpropertyproperty-value-priority) and [style.setPropertyPriority(property, priority)](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setpropertypriorityproperty-priority) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894528/165716).

Comment: @user123444555621, Premasagar. Might as well use the better option: `element.style.setProperty`.

Comment: I'm trying to set a variable value as the property value, but I cannot use this syntax: `html.style.cssText = "background-color: \`${bgColor}\` !important;";` or `html.setAttribute("style","background-color: \`${bgColor}\` !important;");` neither. How can I do that?

Comment: This works better for me. Using setProperty method overrides existing style

Answer (score 307):

`element.style` has a `setProperty` method that can take the priority as a third parameter:

```
element.style.setProperty("display", "inline", "important")
```

It [didn't work in old IEs](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t46) but it should be fine in current browsers.

Comment: Works in IE 9 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Best solution, since it does not override the whole style attribute and is the way W3C meant it to work.

Comment: its downside is I can't use property names in camelCase like `boxShadow`

Comment: @Pavan It's easy to just use the hyphenated form instead, or if you need to automatically convert it just write a function.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Premasagar's excellent answer; if you don't want to remove all the other inline styles use this

```js
//accepts the hyphenated versions (i.e. not 'cssFloat')
addStyle(element, property, value, important) {
    //remove previously defined property
    if (element.style.setProperty)
        element.style.setProperty(property, '');
    else
        element.style.setAttribute(property, '');

    //insert the new style with all the old rules
    element.setAttribute('style', element.style.cssText +
        property + ':' + value + ((important) ? ' !important' : '') + ';');
}
```

<sub>Can't use `removeProperty()` because it wont remove `!important` rules in Chrome.

Can't use `element.style[property] = ''` because it only accepts camelCase in FireFox.</sub>

Comment: Might as well use the better option: `element.style.setProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update / add single style in DOM Element style attribute you can use this function:

```
function setCssTextStyle(el, style, value) {
  var result = el.style.cssText.match(new RegExp("(?:[;\\s]|^)(" +
      style.replace("-", "\\-") + "\\s*:(.*?)(;|$))")),
    idx;
  if (result) {
    idx = result.index + result[0].indexOf(result[1]);
    el.style.cssText = el.style.cssText.substring(0, idx) +
      style + ": " + value + ";" +
      el.style.cssText.substring(idx + result[1].length);
  } else {
    el.style.cssText += " " + style + ": " + value + ";";
  }
}
```

[style.cssText is **supported for all major browsers**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t30).

Use case example:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elementId");
setCssTextStyle(elem, "margin-top", "10px !important");
```

[Here is link to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mark087/dtevfn7c/61/)

Comment: What extra information or improvement does this answer provide ?

Comment: This function is short, simple and easy to understand. You can add important option. It doesn't removing all element styles. It overwriting or adding single style in element styles attibute. You don't need any JS frameworks. And the most important thing is that this function is working in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

First create a class them called with `element.classList`

```
.nonez{display: none!important}

var element = document.getElementById("search_pickup_address");
element.classList.add("nonez")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is adding css to the page, then I would suggest you use the Stylish addon, and write a user style instead of a user script, because a user style is more efficient and appropriate.

See [this page with information on how to create a user style](http://userstyles.org/help/coding)

Comment: Modifying the css is only a part of what my gm extension does

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

use initial property in css3

```
 <p style="color:red!important"> 
    this text is red 
       <em style="color:initial"> 
          this text is in the initial color (e.g. black)
       </em>
    this is red again
 </p>
```

Comment: Initial doesn't reset important. You're not setting the p's color but the em's color. Indeed, change color:initial to color:green and it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xk6Ut/256/

One option to override CSS class in JavaScript is using an ID for the style element so that we can update the CSS class

```
function writeStyles(styleName, cssText) {
    var styleElement = document.getElementById(styleName);
    if (styleElement) document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(
        styleElement);
    styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.type = 'text/css';
    styleElement.id = styleName;
    styleElement.innerHTML = cssText;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
}
```

..

```
   var cssText = '.testDIV{ height:' + height + 'px !important; }';
    writeStyles('styles_js', cssText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than injecting style, if you inject a class(for eg: 'show') through java script, it will work. But here you need css like below. the added class css rule should be below your original rule.

```
td.EvenRow a{
  display: none !important;
}

td.EvenRow a.show{
  display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There we have another possibility to remove a property value from the CSS.

Like using the replace method in js. But you have to know exactly the ID of the style, or you can write a for loop to detecting that by (count styles on the page, then check if any of those 'includes' or 'match' an `!important` value. & you can count also - how much contains them, or just simply write a global [regexp: /str/gi] replacing method)

Mine is very simple, but I attach a jsBin, for example:

https://jsbin.com/geqodeg/edit?html,css,js,output

First I set the body background in CSS for yellow `!important`, then I overrided by JS for darkPink.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a snippet of code to set the important parameter for the style attribute using jquery.

```
$.fn.setFixedStyle = function(styles){
    var s = $(this).attr("style");
    s = "{"+s.replace(/;/g,",").replace(/'|"/g,"");
    s = s.substring(0,s.length-1)+"}";
    s = s.replace(/,/g,"\",\"").replace(/{/g,"{\"").replace(/}/g,"\"}").replace(/:/g,"\":\"");
    var stOb = JSON.parse(s),st;
    if(!styles){
     $.each(stOb,function(k,v){
      stOb[k] +=" !important";
     });
    }
    else{
     $.each(styles,function(k,v){
      if(v.length>0){
        stOb[k] = v+" !important";
      }else{
        stOb[k] += " !important";  
      }
     });
    }
    var ns = JSON.stringify(stOb);
    $(this).attr("style",ns.replace(/"|{|}/g,"").replace(/,/g,";"));
};
```

Usage is pretty simple.Just pass an object containing all the attributes you want to set as important.

```
$("#i1").setFixedStyle({"width":"50px","height":""});
```

There are two additional options.

1.To just add important parameter to already present style attribute pass empty string.

2.To add important param for all attributes present dont pass anything. It will set all attributes as important.

Here is it live in action. http://codepen.io/agaase/pen/nkvjr