# How to apply !important using .css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble applying a style that is `!important`. I’ve tried:

```js
$("#elem").css("width", "100px !important");
```

This does **nothing**; no width style whatsoever is applied. Is there a jQuery-ish way of applying such a style without having to overwrite `cssText` (which would mean I’d need to parse it first, etc.)?

**Edit**: I should add that I have a stylesheet with an `!important` style that I am trying to override with an `!important` style inline, so using `.width()` and the like does not work since it gets overridden by my external `!important` style.

Also, the value that will override the previous value **is computed**, so I cannot simply create another external style.

Comment: Worth noting is that this actually works in Chrome (for me at least), but not in Firefox.

Comment: This also works for me in Chrome 17.x and Safari 5.1.1, but not in FF 8.0.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Chromium 20.0.x using JQuery 1.8.2.

Comment: [jQuery bug #11173](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173) was about fixing `.css` and `!important` in jQuery core. The bug was closed as “won’t fix”. However, that bug’s test case was not as restrictive as the one in this question – the test case did not have an inline `!important` style it was trying to override. Thus, the proposed workaround in that bug will not work in this case.

Comment: If you don't care about IE 8 and under, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25100304/1101095

Comment: I've opened [jQuery bug #2837](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2837) to get this fixed. Hopefully that one won't get closed for no good reason.

Comment: ... aaand jQuery have decided that they won't fix this bug because "just use a plugin". Yay for open source.

Comment: After stranded on this SO answer i decided to remind me on this https://xkcd.com/912/ and use less again :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding !important with css or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overriding-important-with-css-or-jquery) -- While this one is older, and more highly voted, the other one's got the clearest, most valuable answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Most of these answers are now outdated, IE7 support is not an issue.

The best way to do this that **supports IE11+ and all modern browsers** is:

```
const $elem = $("#elem");
$elem[0].style.setProperty('width', '100px', 'important');
```

---

Or if you want, you can create a small jQuery plugin that does this.
This plugin closely matches jQuery's own `css()` method in the parameters it supports:

```
/**
 * Sets a CSS style on the selected element(s) with !important priority.
 * This supports camelCased CSS style property names and calling with an object 
 * like the jQuery `css()` method. 
 * Unlike jQuery's css() this does NOT work as a getter.
 * 
 * @param {string|Object<string, string>} name
 * @param {string|undefined} value
 */   
jQuery.fn.cssImportant = function(name, value) {
  const $this = this;
  const applyStyles = (n, v) => {
    // Convert style name from camelCase to dashed-case.
    const dashedName = n.replace(/(.)([A-Z])(.)/g, (str, m1, upper, m2) => {
      return m1 + "-" + upper.toLowerCase() + m2;
    }); 
    // Loop over each element in the selector and set the styles.
    $this.each(function(){
      this.style.setProperty(dashedName, v, 'important');
    });
  };
  // If called with the first parameter that is an object,
  // Loop over the entries in the object and apply those styles. 
  if(jQuery.isPlainObject(name)){
    for(const [n, v] of Object.entries(name)){
       applyStyles(n, v);
    }
  } else {
    // Otherwise called with style name and value.
    applyStyles(name, value);
  }
  // This is required for making jQuery plugin calls chainable.
  return $this;
};
```

```
// Call the new plugin:
$('#elem').cssImportant('height', '100px');

// Call with an object and camelCased style names:
$('#another').cssImportant({backgroundColor: 'salmon', display: 'block'});

// Call on multiple items:
$('.item, #foo, #bar').cssImportant('color', 'red');
```

[Example jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8rytensh/8/).

Answer (score 736):

The problem is caused by jQuery not understanding the `!important` attribute, and as such fails to apply the rule.

You might be able to work around that problem, and apply the rule by referring to it, via `addClass()`:

```css
.importantRule { width: 100px !important; }
```

```js
$('#elem').addClass('importantRule');
```

Or by using `attr()`:

```
$('#elem').attr('style', 'width: 100px !important');
```

The latter approach would unset any previously set in-line style rules, though. So use with care.

Of course, there's a good argument that @Nick Craver's method is easier/wiser.

The above, `attr()` approach modified slightly to preserve the original `style` string/properties, and modified as suggested by [falko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506724/falko) in a comment:

```
$('#elem').attr('style', function(i,s) { return (s || '') + 'width: 100px !important;' });
```

Comment: i am leaning toward your latter approach, but what is sad about it is that ill probably end up having to parse the previous cssText because i cant just discard it

Comment: @ricebowl np, i made a quick test, what you're saying unfortunately won't work in this example. Browsers put a higher priority to styles which are defined to an ID rather than a class. see. http://sinan.kodingen.com/csstest.html

Comment: @Sinan Y., I was rather foolishly, and optimistically, hoping that there wasn't a contradictory rule set in the ID-related rules. I was also hoping, to be entirely honest, that `!important` would override those that were (unless they were also specified with `!important`). Still, at least my final '@Nick Craver's method is easier/wiser' holds true! ^.^

Comment: btw Nick Craver's method is no different than yours...:) just another way of writing it with jquery... changing style attribute or changing cssText with jquery's css method does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Sinan Y., yeah, I know; I was just being all self-deprecating and English about it... =b

Comment: ah, sorry couldn't get it, sometimes English humour goes beyond my understanding...:)

Comment: What's with the nested quotes ('"width: 100px !important"')? That didn't work for me, but when I removed the inner quotes it worked. Thanks!

Comment: [A variation on the `attr()` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11723492/578288) without the problem of unsetting previously-set inline style rules.

Comment: small fix when style is empty:
$('#elem').attr('style', function(i,s) { return (s||'') + 'width: 100px !important;' });

Comment: You should add @falko's fix, as in firefox your last snippet will set style to `'undefinedwidth: 100px !important;'` when the current style is empty.

Comment: the last method worked for me, but I had to add a preceding `;` to the style I wanted to add .. for whatever reason, even though the original element's inline style had the attribute closure, it wasn't coming through in `s`

Comment: This should be the absolute answer as the previous, accepted solution, is a rather nasty hack typical of jquery code, seen all too often.

Comment: You should also add @falko's fix for IE too as it shows 'undefinedwidth: 100px !important;' on there too. (IE11 to be specific).

Comment: if later you want to remove the `!important` of the same element using the same method you can use `s.replace('width: 100px !important;', '')`

Answer (score 344):

I think I've found a solution. I've made it into a new function:

`jQuery.style(name, value, priority);`

You can use it to get values with `.style('name')` just like `.css('name')`, get the [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) with `.style()`, and also set values, with the ability to specify the priority as *'important'*. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration).

### Example

```
var div = $('someDiv');
console.log(div.style('color'));
div.style('color', 'red');
console.log(div.style('color'));
div.style('color', 'blue', 'important');
console.log(div.style('color'));
console.log(div.style().getPropertyPriority('color'));
```

**Example output:**

```
null
red
blue
important
```

---

### The Function

```
(function($) {    
  if ($.fn.style) {
    return;
  }

  // Escape regex chars with \
  var escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  };

  // For those who need them (< IE 9), add support for CSS functions
  var isStyleFuncSupported = !!CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.getPropertyValue;
  if (!isStyleFuncSupported) {
    CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.getPropertyValue = function(a) {
      return this.getAttribute(a);
    };
    CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty = function(styleName, value, priority) {
      this.setAttribute(styleName, value);
      var priority = typeof priority != 'undefined' ? priority : '';
      if (priority != '') {
        // Add priority manually
        var rule = new RegExp(escape(styleName) + '\\s*:\\s*' + escape(value) +
            '(\\s*;)?', 'gmi');
        this.cssText =
            this.cssText.replace(rule, styleName + ': ' + value + ' !' + priority + ';');
      }
    };
    CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.removeProperty = function(a) {
      return this.removeAttribute(a);
    };
    CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.getPropertyPriority = function(styleName) {
      var rule = new RegExp(escape(styleName) + '\\s*:\\s*[^\\s]*\\s*!important(\\s*;)?',
          'gmi');
      return rule.test(this.cssText) ? 'important' : '';
    }
  }

  // The style function
  $.fn.style = function(styleName, value, priority) {
    // DOM node
    var node = this.get(0);
    // Ensure we have a DOM node
    if (typeof node == 'undefined') {
      return this;
    }
    // CSSStyleDeclaration
    var style = this.get(0).style;
    // Getter/Setter
    if (typeof styleName != 'undefined') {
      if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
        // Set style property
        priority = typeof priority != 'undefined' ? priority : '';
        style.setProperty(styleName, value, priority);
        return this;
      } else {
        // Get style property
        return style.getPropertyValue(styleName);
      }
    } else {
      // Get CSSStyleDeclaration
      return style;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration) for examples of how to read and set the CSS values. My issue was that I had already set `!important` for the width in my CSS to avoid conflicts with other theme CSS, but any changes I made to the width in jQuery would be unaffected since they would be added to the style attribute.

### Compatibility

For setting with the priority using the [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) function, [This Article](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdpsdnb.php) says there is support for IE 9+ and all other browsers. I have tried with IE 8 and it has failed, which is why I built support for it in my functions (see above). It will work on all other browsers using `setProperty`, but it will need my custom code to work in < IE 9.

Comment: have you tested this on other browsers?

Comment: See my updates, I've built support for IE8 and lower, and it works fine in IE9 (as stated in the links) and of course all other browsers.

Comment: Ah, I didn't test it in IE6, but surely IE7 has superseded it there :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009294/can-this-solution-be-ie7-and-ie6-compatible

Comment: There is also the [jQuery.important plugin](https://github.com/premasagar/important) that was published a couple years ago.  I'm using it in production with only one minor issue (see their Issues tab.

Comment: Sadly, this solution does not work in IE8 running in IE7 compatibility mode, as CSSStyleDeclaration is not available.

Comment: `CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.getPropertyValue` returns `undefined` in IE8, not `null`. The IE8 polyfill did *not* work until I changed `null` to `undefined` (I actually check for both just to be safe...).

Comment: Also, `text.replace(...)` falls apart if `text` isn't... text. For example, I was getting `0` (an int) in `text`, and this issue was solved by editing the `Regex.escape` function to return `(text + '').replace(...)`.

Comment: $( '.someclass' ).each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty( 'border', 'none', 'important' );
});

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overwriting-important-with-css-or-jquery

Simpler, cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: The only good way to deal with this is using classes, not direct style injection.

Comment: @Richard, the only good way to deal with this is *not* to use `!important` in your styles, at least for things you're going to change with jQuery... As long as they are *your* styles. If your code runs within a page coded by a student who works around his ignorance of specificity rules by slapping `!important` on every second style, you are going to ram head first into one of these `!importants` sooner or later.

Comment: @Septagram Few years passed since your comment, please go and tell them Bootstrap 4 people what you said... They have classes to add borders, and they all have `!important` in the stylesheet.

Comment: The best answer is to use the **attr()** propetry as @David Thomas suggested.

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm not sure I completely agree with the use of `attr()` as the "best" answer - it is at least "pure vanilla" jquery, but it is rather ridiculous to have to type `$('#elem').attr('style', function(i,s) { return (s || '') + 'width: 100px !important;' });
` and to not be able to set a particular style attribute that has already been set with it.

Answer (score 161):

You can set the width directly using [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) like this:

```
$("#elem").width(100);
```

**Updated for comments:**
You have this option as well, but it'll replace all css on the element, so not sure it's any more viable:

```
$('#elem').css('cssText', 'width: 100px !important');
```

Comment: ok, i used with as an example, what i care about is setting !important.

Comment: also i edited the question to reflect my situation better.. basically i have an external !important width that is set to something bad that i must override inline. width() does not work for this reason

Comment: @mkoryak - Updated with the only other non-class option, not sure if it'll fit your situation or not.

Comment: But it will override any other style directly applied to the element. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11723492/491044 is the easiest to implement.

Comment: prevent overrides by `$('#elem').css('cssText', $('#elem').css('cssText')+'width: 100px !important');` concat it with the previous value

Answer (score 95):

```
const elem = $("#elem");
elem[0].style.removeAttribute('width');
elem[0].style.setProperty('width', '100px', 'important');
```

Note:
Using Chrome may return an error such as:

> elem[0].style.removeAttribute is not a function

Changing the line to use the `.removeProperty` function such as to `elem[0].style.removeProperty('width');` fixed the issue.

Comment: This is one of the best answers. Simple and it works. And it doesn't require much explanation. It's just regular JavaScript, except for the jQuery selector. jQuery doesn't provide support for "important" so using regular JS is the way to go

Comment: If you wanna go Vanilla with it, just make `var = document.getElementById('elem');` and perform the style methods on elem (as opposed to elem[0]).  Cheers.

Comment: In vanilla JS, removeAttribute does not work. Do the following.

`var style = document.getElementById('elem');
style.removeProperty('width');
style.setProperty('width, '100px', 'important')`

Comment: Also had problems with `.removeAttribute`. It seems to be an [IE-only method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhutuuj.php). @mcoenca comment is right; `.removeProperty` works fine. It's IE9+ according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How to apply styling to next() node? `elem[0].next().style...` dosn't work.

Comment: @Dejan, sorry for very late answer, but this should work: `elem.next().get(0).style...`

Comment: elem[0].style.removeAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 58):

[David Thomas’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655976/578288) describes a way to use `$('#elem').attr('style', …)`, but warns that using it will delete previously-set styles in the `style` attribute. Here is a way of using `attr()` without that problem:

```js
var $elem = $('#elem');
$elem.attr('style', $elem.attr('style') + '; ' + 'width: 100px !important');
```

As a function:

```js
function addStyleAttribute($element, styleAttribute) {
    $element.attr('style', $element.attr('style') + '; ' + styleAttribute);
}
```

```js
addStyleAttribute($('#elem'), 'width: 100px !important');
```

Here is a [JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/atulek/4/edit).

Comment: `addStyleAttribute()` could also be modified to take the same parameters as [jQuery’s `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2). For instance, it could support taking a map of CSS properties to their values. If you did that, you would basically be re-implementing `.css()` with the `!important` bug fixed but without any optimizations.

Comment: This worked well for me since the width was defined in a CSS class and I needed to override it dynamically with a value calculated based on the width of the browser window and content.

Answer (score 34):

After reading other answers and experimenting, this is what works for me:

```
$(".selector")[0].style.setProperty( 'style', 'value', 'important' );
```

This doesn't work in IE 8 and under, though.

Comment: and since we still have to support IE8 (some of us, the unlucky) - this is not good.

Answer (score 30):

You can do this:

```
$("#elem").css("cssText", "width: 100px !important;");
```

Using "cssText" as the property name and whatever you want added to the CSS as its value.

Comment: the downside of this is that it will overwrite whatever `cssText` was in there before - so you cant really use it freely

Comment: anyway, you can use $("#elem").css("cssText", "+=;width: 100px !important;");

Comment: Don't forget you can use tilda string quotes to include variables: eg. ```element.css({ 'cssText': `top: ${xTop}px !important` });```

Answer (score 19):

You can achieve this in two ways:

```
$("#elem").prop("style", "width: 100px !important"); // this is not supported in chrome
$("#elem").attr("style", "width: 100px !important");
```

Comment: Actually, the [`.prop()` function](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) was added in jQuery v1.6 and will work in Chrome... this is quoted from the prop page: Before jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Comment: Not a very good idea for a generic solution. You might override your existing style using this.

Answer (score 14):

There's no need to go to the complexity of @AramKocharyan's answer, nor the need to insert any style tags dynamically.

Just overwrite style, ***but*** you don't have to parse anything, why would you?

```js
// Accepts the hyphenated versions (i.e. not 'cssFloat')
function addStyle(element, property, value, important) {
    // Remove previously defined property
    if (element.style.setProperty)
        element.style.setProperty(property, '');
    else
        element.style.setAttribute(property, '');

    // Insert the new style with all the old rules
    element.setAttribute('style', element.style.cssText +
        property + ':' + value + ((important) ? ' !important' : '') + ';');
}
```

<sub>Can't use `removeProperty()`, because it won't remove `!important` rules in Chrome.

Can't use `element.style[property] = ''`, because it only accepts camelCase in Firefox.</sub>

You could probably make this shorter with jQuery, but this vanilla function will run on modern browsers, Internet Explorer 8, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I did after encountering this problem...

```
var origStyleContent = jQuery('#logo-example').attr('style');
jQuery('#logo-example').attr('style', origStyleContent + ';width:150px !important');
```

Comment: Thank you, this is far simpler to implement than a custom plugin (even if it does potentially destroy other inline styles).

Answer (score 9):

This solution doesn't override any of the previous styles, it just applies the one you need:

```
var heightStyle = "height: 500px !important";
if ($("foo").attr('style')) {
  $("foo").attr('style', heightStyle + $("foo").attr('style').replace(/^height: [-,!,0-9,a-z, A-Z, ]*;/,''));
else {
  $("foo").attr('style', heightStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest and best solution for this problem from me was to simply use addClass() instead of .css() or .attr().

For example:

`$('#elem').addClass('importantClass');`

And in your CSS file:

```
.importantClass {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Since the width is computed in JavaScript this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If it is not so relevant and since you're dealing with one element which is `#elem`, you can change its id to something else and style it as you wish...

```
$('#elem').attr('id', 'cheaterId');
```

And in your CSS:

```
#cheaterId { width: 100px;}
```

Comment: why do you change the id to apply a css instead of just add a css class?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using the `css()` function try the `addClass()` function:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").addClass("exampleClass");
  });
  </script>

  <style>
  .exampleClass{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
  }
  </style>
```

Comment: The OP wrote that the value of the property is calculated dynamically, so your answer doesn't work for him.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  I don't think I have the exact needs as the original poster but it does work where css() does not.

Comment: This is indeed a perfectly reasonable solution to a problem... just not **this** problem!

Answer (score 7):

FYI, it doesn't work because jQuery doesn't support it. There was a ticket filed on 2012 ([#11173 $(elem).css("property", "value !important") fails](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173)) that was eventually closed as WONTFIX.

Answer (score 6):

We need first to remove the previous style. I remove it using a regular expression. Here is an example for changing color:

```
var SetCssColorImportant = function (jDom, color) {
       var style = jDom.attr('style');
       style = style.replace(/color: .* !important;/g, '');
       jDom.css('cssText', 'color: ' + color + ' !important;' + style); }
```

Comment: Don't know why so many solutions hack a style tag onto the element when the cssText method works just fine... e.g. `$selector.css('cssText','margin-bottom: 0 !important')`

Comment: @frumbert Bu the `cssText` will replace the existing styles within it,

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way to append style in head:

```
$('head').append('<style> #elm{width:150px !important} </style>');
```

This appends style after all your CSS files so it will have higher priority than other CSS files and will be applied.

Answer (score 6):

May be it look's like this:

#### Cache

```
var node = $('.selector')[0];
OR
var node = document.querySelector('.selector');
```

#### Set CSS

```
node.style.setProperty('width', '100px', 'important');
```

#### Remove CSS

```
node.style.removeProperty('width');
OR
node.style.width = '';
```

Answer (score 6):

I think it works OK and can overwrite any other CSS before (this: DOM element):

```
this.setAttribute('style', 'padding:2px !important');
```

Answer (score 5):

Do it like this:

```
$("#elem").get(0).style.width= "100px!important";
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution will leave all the computed javascript and add the important tag into the element:
You can do (Ex if you need to set the width with the important tag)

```
$('exampleDiv').css('width', '');
//This will remove the width of the item
var styles = $('exampleDiv').attr('style');
//This will contain all styles in your item
//ex: height:auto; display:block;
styles += 'width: 200px !important;'
//This will add the width to the previous styles
//ex: height:auto; display:block; width: 200px !important;
$('exampleDiv').attr('style', styles);
//This will add all previous styles to your item
```

Answer (score 4):

## Three working examples

I had a similar situation, but I used .find() after struggling with .closest() for a long time with many variations.

#### The Example Code

```
// Allows contain functions to work, ignores case sensitivity

jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
    result = false;
    theList = meta[3].split("','");
    var contents = (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '')
    for (x=0; x<theList.length; x++) {
        if (contents.toLowerCase().indexOf(theList[x].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() {
        $("#out:contains('foo', 'test456')").find(".inner").css('width', '50px', 'important');
    }, 1000); // Rescans every 1000 ms
});
```

#### Alternative

```
$('.inner').each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty('height', '50px', 'important');
});

$('#out').find('.inner').css({ 'height': '50px'});
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/fx4mbp6c/

Comment: I will spare you a down vote but you should opt to replace the `.indexOf()` function with something that is more cross-browser compatible.  Use, rather, `.match()` or `.test()` instead of `.indexOf()`

Comment: Why no semicolon in the line with `var contents = `?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume you tried it without adding `!important`?

Inline CSS (which is how JavaScript adds styling) overrides the stylesheet CSS. I'm pretty sure that's the case even when the stylesheet CSS rule has `!important`.

Another question (maybe a stupid question but must be asked.):  Is the element you are trying to work on `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`?

Not knowing your expertise in CSS...  inline elements don't always behave as you would expect.

Comment: css rules that have !important override everything, no matter where they are located, only exception being that inline styles with !important will override stylesheet styles with !important. This is the problem i am having. there is a stylesheet rule with !important that i would like to override. whats more, the value i need to supply must be computed through JS, so i cant simply change the stylesheet itself.

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not be appropriate for your situation but you can use CSS selectors for a lot of these type of situations.

If, for example you wanted of the 3rd and 6th instances of .cssText to have a different width you could write:

```
.cssText:nth-of-type(3), .cssText:nth-of-type(6) {width:100px !important;}
```

Or:

```
.container:nth-of-type(3).cssText, .container:nth-of-type(6).cssText {width:100px !important;}
```

Comment: This does *not* match the 3rd and 6th instances of `.cssText`. `:nth-of-type()` does not do what you think it does. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) for an explanation.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did read the link, but I'm not sure I have understood your point.  Here's a fiddle showing this working as intended:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2E4b/

Comment: In your fiddle, you're dealing with a series of `li` elements. They are all of the same element type `li`, which is what the selector deals with. If you were to mix different elements in the same parent, then `:nth-of-type()` would behave differently, especially so once you add a class selector into the mix.

Answer (score 3):

We can use setProperty or cssText to add `!important` to a DOM element using JavaScript.

Example 1:

```
elem.style.setProperty ("color", "green", "important");
```

Example 2:

```
elem.style.cssText='color: red !important;'
```

Answer (score 2):

I also discovered that certain elements or add-on's (like Bootstrap) have some special class cases where they do not play well with `!important` or other work-arounds like `.addClass/.removeClass`, and thus you have to to toggle them on/off.

For example, if you use something like `<table class="table-hover">`the only way to successfully modify elements like colors of rows is to toggle the `table-hover` class on/off, like this

`$(your_element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");`

Hopefully this work-around will be helpful to someone! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to change a text color of a menu-item when "event". The best way I found when I had this same problem was:

First step: Create, in your CSS, a new class with this purpose, for example:

```
.colorw{ color: white !important;}
```

Last step: Apply this class using the addClass method as follows:

```
$('.menu-item>a').addClass('colorw');
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Not however if you want to generate CSS value with the js, forexample the color value defined in JS. Otherwise this is nice.

Comment: why would you want to define a color in js?

Answer (score 1):

The safest workaround to this is to add a class and then do the magic in CSS :-), `addClass()` and `removeClass()` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xk6Ut/256/

An alternative approach is  dynamically creating and updating CSS class in JavaScript. To do that, we can use style element and need to employ the ID for the style element so that we can update the CSS class

```
function writeStyles(styleName, cssText) {
    var styleElement = document.getElementById(styleName);
    if (styleElement) document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(
        styleElement);
    styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.type = 'text/css';
    styleElement.id = styleName;
    styleElement.innerHTML = cssText;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
}
```

...

```
  var cssText = '.testDIV{ height:' + height + 'px !important; }';
  writeStyles('styles_js', cssText)
```

Answer (score -6):

Another easy method to solve this issue adding the style attribute:

```
$('.selector').attr('style', 'width:500px !important');
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it would replace any other styles in the `style` attribute instead of just changing/adding the `width` property.