# !important javascript css where would it go

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript file containing css :

```
a(this).css({
    position:"fixed",
    top: "210px",
    left: "1450px" ,
    width: "30px", 
    height: "30px", 
    margin: "0", 
    padding: "0", 
    minWidth: "65px", 
    listStyleType: "none", 
    zIndex: 1e7
});
```

The top and left seems to get changed somewhere else when I resize the screen. Where to I add `!important` to them to see if that works?

Comment: `top: "210px !important"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824079/using-important-in-jquerys-css-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a(this).css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": "210px !important",
    "left": "1450px !important",
    "width": "30px",
    "height": "30px",
    "margin": "0",
    "padding": "0",
    "minWidth": "65px",
    "listStyleType": "none",
    "zIndex": 1e7
});
```

But if you are changing so many values, I advise you to use a class instead. If the above doesn't work:

- Are you sure `a(this)` refers to the right element?
- Look for the file/plugin that overrides the values - you should always do this rather than just putting an `!important` there

Comment: @user3328513 See my edit. Also `1e7` doesn't seem to me to be a valid value.

Comment: If this didnt work, use inspector in chrome (F12) or right click the element and select Inspect Element. ON the right hand column, you will see all the CSS styles applied...

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: JavaScript number literals can be specified in scientific notation, so `1e7` is `10000000`. (At least in Firefox it works anyway.)

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. (Quite a high value though...)