# Use element inner text as CSS value on a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the text inside the first div of an element as the CSS color value on a different element. Here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
<style>
  h1.page-title {
    color: red !important;
  }    
</style>

<div id="field">
  <div style="font-size:0;">#666!important</div>
  <div style="font-size:0;">second div</div>
</div>

<h1 class="page-title">hello</h1>

<script>
$(function() {
  var x = $("#field div:first").text();
  $("h1.page-title").css("color", x);
});
</script>
```

So far the Javascript/jQuery code doesn't seem to be working for me, but I don't know why. Is there any way to accomplish this? Please keep in mind that modifying the HTML code in any way wouldn't be ideal.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `:first` a jQuery thing or did you mean `:first-child`?

Comment: It's a jQuery selector, similar to :first-of-type on CSS, I think.

Comment: Wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass "!important" to JQuery's CSS (or at least, not like that). Drop that and it works.

You could:

a. Change it to something like `$("h1.page-title").css('cssText', 'color:' + x);` ("cssText" will add what you pass as a string.) – or see some of the other answers to "how to apply '!important' in jQuery" linked below.

b. Don't use `!important` if possible. There's really no reason you should have an *inline* important, unless the CSS having an important is completely out of your control.

---

[Using !important in jQuery's css() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824079/using-important-in-jquerys-css-function)

[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)