# CSS !important doesn't seem to work in jQuery/Firefox 3.x

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/P2sLa/

In Chrome, this works fine, but in Firefox it does not, and yields a Javascript warning. I know the !important isn't required here, but I have a large-scale project where it is required, and it's causing Firefox to break. Any ideas?

Comment: `!important` works fine in FF 3.x for me... can you provide more code here?

Comment: @pixelbobby... it doesn't work in FF 4, the error given is `Warning: Expected end of value but found '!'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.`

Comment: Can you explain why it's "required" in your project?  It really doesn't make any sense, since element styles always trump styles from stylesheets anyway (as far as I know).

Comment: @pixelbobby It doesn't work in FF 3.6 for me either, but I don't get a Javascript error.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack, that's not jQuery's fault. Setting `!important` dynamically on CSS properties is only supported by a few browsers. See [this bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066).

Comment: see: [Jquery css: applying !important styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)

Comment: @Pointy: Suppose the background for #box was `red !important` and the OP could not change that. That would require setting `!important` to the new value as well, otherwise it will have no effect. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/P2sLa/5/

Comment: Hmm ... very interesting.  Learn something every day I guess :-)

Comment: @Pointy Sure, the reason it's required is because I already have Superfish changing the background color dynamically, so I have a special case set up where clicking the menu item puts a graphic in the background. Without !important, nothing happens because the Superfish dynamic CSS wins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching for "jquery css important" brought up [a blog post explaining the "problem"](http://hungred.com/how-to/jquery-javascript-css-important/).
I'll post some additional information, but to make a long story short, [here's your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsGXk/1/):

```
$('#set-bg').click(function() {
    $('#box').css('cssText', 'background: blue !important');
});
```

The author states that:

> This is not a bug but something that
>   most browser doesn’t acknowledge a
>   need since inline style already have
>   the highest priority other than user
>   defined ones. (unless you do not want
>   your user to change how they view your
>   website).

Please note that using [cssText](http://hungred.com//goto/http://burbank.directrouter.com/~robertco/administrator/index.php) has one disadvantage and you might want to consider
using [cssRules](http://hungred.com//goto/http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/cssProps.html) instead:

> cssText will overwrites the css of
>   that particular element. Hence, you
>   will have to redeclare the rule for
>   that particular element all over
>   again.

With all that said. Please listen to the author's summary:

> Using !important in CSS is not
>   advisable since it might kill your web
>   usability. Furthermore, there is no
>   reason why !important should be use as
>   inline styling already has the highest
>   priority. Hence, you might want to
>   reconsider applying !important on your
>   script after thinking about the
>   consequences that might bought to your
>   users.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a call to ".attr()" instead of ".css()" ?

Comment: @Pointy, that's indeed a CSS attribute, it maps to `style.cssText`. However, it will override the whole style of the element. According to @rubiii's link, `cssRules` should be used instead to avoid that.

Comment: This will also work: `$('#box').attr('style',$('#box').attr('style')+'background: blue !important;')`

Comment: I added some additional information to my answer, including the author's warning to use cssText and his conclusion to avoid !important. The information is out there ;)