# How to overwrite an !important CSS property in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have css on my page's `body` and I would like to overwrite `overflow: visible !important;`. I have tried the jQuery script below, but that doesn't do it"

```
 jQuery("body, #s4-workspace").css("overflow", "hidden !important");
```

CSS:

```
body, #s4-workspace {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; //overriden
    width: 100%;
}
```

I know there are two overflow already, but sadly I don't have the hand on that, otherwise it would be too easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: or is there a way to just remove overflow: visible !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `! important` is not handled well by jQuery's `css()`.

Here is a hack that will work if you don't mind overwriting the inline `style` attribute value (if it exists):

```
 jQuery("body, #s4-workspace")
     .attr("style", "overflow:hidden !important");
```

Like I said, it's a hack - but give it a try.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dGbaD/

Comment: or is there a way to just remove overflow: visible !important;

Comment: I don't think you can just "remove" it, it must be set to another value. Check the demo and see if that helps, I revised the errors in my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK jQuery does not understand the `!important` part.

Try creating a class, like this:

```
.newClass {
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

And then set the class like this:

```
jQuery("body, #s4-workspace").addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: or is there a way to just remove overflow: visible !important;

Comment: you could remove it if it was set in a class

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't manage !important rules.

See:

[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)

http://hungred.com/how-to/jquery-javascript-css-important/