# Setting display: block !Important

Tags: jquery, css

There is a problem with a rollover doesn't want to show its content and if I do

```css
#callCenter {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2411 !important;
    display: block !important; /* please note here !important */
    right: 110px;
}
```

It's shown, but if I do: (so the div is hidden until another element is clicked)

```css
#callCenter {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2411 !important;
    right: 110px;
}
```

And

```js
$('#telefonosCabecera').click(function(){
    $("#callCenter").css('display','block!important'); // or 'block !important'
    alert('done')
});
```

I don't see `#callCenter` but I do see the alert.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery css: applying !important styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to do one of the following:

1. Add a class with the !important rule (i.e.: `.myClass{display:block !important;}` ) and then add the class to the element
2. Add the css attribute via `$('#myElement').attr('style','display: block !important');`

Comment: tried that but i end up with: <div id="callCenter" style="display: block;" class="displayBlockImportant"> and the style attribute overrides the clasname i think :(

Comment: The inline style ALWAYS overrides the classes. You need to pick only one of the methods. try $('#callCenter').attr('style','display: block !important');

It should do the trick for you.

Comment: I've found another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles/8894528#8894528

Comment: @Phoenix That's not true. If the inline style is not "important", it can be overridden by a class with "important" properties. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpKaA/