# Resize font with jQuery/JS and override font-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

For example, if I have:

```
<div id="divtochangeFont">
    <p>This will change font size</p>
    <p stlye="font-size: 10px">This will not change font size</p>
</div>
```

Now I want to resize font with jQuery in all div content. For example, with simple jQuery:

```
$("#divtochangeFont").css("font-size","16px");
```

But it changes only in first paragraph. How to override all defined font-size attributes in div?

PS: Scale effect can't be used...

Comment: have you tried $("#divtochangeFont p").css("font-size","16px"); ?

Comment: I'd be worried if your browser interpreted `stlye` as `style`.

Comment: Yep you just needed to add a p : http://jsfiddle.net/srGxF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#divtochangeFont * ").css({"font-size": "16px","color": "orange"});
```

you only need to take all children of your div

Comment: What about if there isn't any children - Just text?

Comment: if there isn't children $("#divtochangeFont, #divtochangeFont * ").

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#divtochangeFont, #divtochangeFont *").css("font-size", "16px");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
$("#divtochangeFont").css("font-size","16px");
$("#divtochangeFont").children().each(function () {
  $(this).css("font-size","16px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the font on the parent div, the child p with a font-size of 10px has precedence for that paragraph. (That's the cascading in CSS.)

What frank blizzard suggests will work. Personally, I'd just change your selector if #divtochangeFont only contains p's.

```
$("#divtochangeFont p").css("font-size","16px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, so you won't need to worry about other elements

```
$("#divtochangeFont").addClass("important").css("font-size","16px");
```

[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)