# Overriding 'display' css using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using below css to hide an element :

```
.pds-pd-link {     
    display: none !important; 
}
```

Using jQuery can I enable the display on the css .pds-pd-link

Something like `$(.pds-pd-link).css("display","");` ?

Comment: Here is related answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could do:

```
$(.pds-pd-link).css("display","none");
```

I would suggest:

```
$(.pds-pd-link).hide();
```

Comment: why suggest one over the other ?

Comment: `.hide` uses `dispaly: none`. Using `.hide()` makes for shorter, cleaner and more readable code at no extra cost. Same goes for `.show()` which uses `.css('display', 'xxx')`. where xxx is what ever the display property was initially. If it was not set `block` is used by default.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to correct the OP's original syntax on the use of `.css('display', '...');`

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, yes.

Alternatively, you could use the following to [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the element:

```
$(.pds-pd-link).show();
$(.pds-pd-link).hide();
```

Or you could even use the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to automatically switch between the two:

```
$(.pds-pd-link).toggle();
```

Comment: As a side note: toggle does not perfom as well and is about 3-4 times slower than show/hide and even close to 10 times slower in IE. See here for more details: http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/05/now-you-see-me-showhide-performance

Answer (score -3):

This should work

```
$('.pds-pd-link').css('cssText', 'display: block !important');
```