# How can I set the important flag in a css with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery css: applying !important styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)

I have the following code:

```
$("body")
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'progress' })
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default' })
    });
```

This works but not when I hover over a link where I have a hover and a different cursor. Is there a way that I can set the CSS cursor property above to important with jQuery>

Answer (score 6):

Try this code for example:

```
$(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default !important' })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body")
.ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' })
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default !important' })
});
```

Comment: No down vote by me but I guess because of the other answers saying there are problems with !important. I am still looking at all the links.

Comment: @SamanthaJ there is no problem with me. What is the different among all other answers ans with my answer.. explain

Answer (score 2):

Just add `!important` after your property value:

```
$("body")
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' })
    })
     .ajaxStop(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default  !important' })
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax,

[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)

Comment: How does this line up with the other answers? Now I'm a bit confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles

Comment: You need to add the implementation of your *style* function..

Comment: there is no method `style` for jQuary can you conform your source or show us a demo?

Comment: i tried to post the link, now corrected it