# Custom CSS cursor using JQuery css method

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way I can use JQuery's .css() method to give the following cursor style?:

```
cursor: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur), default !important;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery doesn't understand the `!important`, so if you remove that it'll work:

```
$('selector').css({
    'cursor': 'url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur), default'});
```

There are ways to get around it, why not use a CSS class?

```
/* CSS */
.cursor {
    cursor: url('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur'), default !important;
}
```

So you can just:

```
$('selector').addClass('cursor');
```

There are other alternatives too, see: [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles)

Comment: I'm using JQuery UI Sortable which takes a cursor option and sets the cursor style using .css().  I've tried handling cursor changing with mouse events but have ran into trouble of resetting the cursor.  Using the library's cursor option give me the expected cursor resetting.

Comment: If you use the `<a>` element, then you can do this in CSS `a:hover{ cursor: .... }` and get around not using JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvPvL/3/) using the below code, but yes as mentioned above I removed the `!important` which made it work.

```
$('#cursor').css(        
    'cursor','url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur),default'
);
```