# How to reset a directive in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as basis for my style sheets. If I want something to look different as defined in the `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap-theme.css` I simply override it in my custom CSS files, that are loaded after the Bootstrap files. But now I have following case:

**`bootstrap.css`**

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      background: transparent !important;
      color: #000 !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
      text-shadow: none !important;
    }
    ...
}
```

I want, that the `background` for printing is the same as for the `screen`.

**How can I "reset" the `background` directive of Bootstrap (without to touch the `bootstrap.css`)?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to override / remove background: none!important with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838007/is-it-possible-to-override-remove-background-noneimportant-with-jquery)

Comment: No, it does not. since that question is about "PURE jQuery and NOT editing of any stylesheets".

Comment: Have you checked the first answer to that question?

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17838092/2019043)? Yes. It's no, what I want to achieve (s. my explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117219/how-to-reset-a-directive-in-css/39117310#comment65581620_39117310)).

Comment: Ah, I see, that indeed obfuscates the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should create a custom CSS / LESS file, called maybe `bootstrap-overrides.css` with the following:

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: newValue!important;
    }
}
```

And place it in the head, after the bootstrap declaration, so you can easily overwrite the background value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it would only work, if I have one single background color for everything. It's not the goal. I want, that the BG colors are kept for `print` exactly as they are defined for `screen`.

Comment: Then you'll just have to not include that part. You can import from here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ all the bootstrap components except the print.