# jQuery - Making fadeOUt use !important

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, widget

I have created a jQuery widget for other people to embed on their website, and within the widget I am using a css reset stylesheet called "cleanslate" from here:

https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate

This stops the page style creeping into my widget.

Problem is that my fadeOut and fadeIn's are no longer working because the reset style is overriding the `display` inline style jQuery is adding. I need to make the fadeOut function add `!important;` to the inline style.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The !important is pertaining to CSS. You cannot apply it to jQuery. Can you paste your code

Comment: look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery

hope that helped.

Comment: @MarsOne I want jQuery to add !important to the `display:` style it adds to the element when I use `$('#element').fadeOut('slow');` <-- all that does is add display: none, and drop the opacity. I need it to add `display: none !important`...

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: I just did... `$('#element').fadeOut('slow');` #element is a <div>

Comment: I came up with a solution below. Seems to work OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with the solution below, hope it helps someone else in the same situation.

All comments / improvements welcome:

```
    jQuery("element").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        jQuery("element").attr("style", "display: none !important");
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: for me at the end there is no fadeout effect, but it will hide