# changing multiple 'CSS' using Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, attr

Here is my code:

```
var showThis = $(this).attr('id'); // div0, div1, div2 etc.
$('#' + showThis).attr('style', 'background-color: #063 !important, height: 520px');
```

I need the change the background-color, width and height of

```
#showThis
```

using the method used above since I cannot add or switch Classes (it breaks the rest of my code if I add a class to #showThis). Now what I have above works, however, it only changes the background-color height. I need to change the width as well. When I add

```
width: 20px
```

like so

at the end of it, it doesn't work for some reason. It stops changing both the width and height, changes the background-color. It doesn't give any javascript errors so the code works and the line does execute since it does change the background-color, but how come it doesn't change the width and height yet it only changes the one of the two?

Note: I need to use the !important tag (so I don't think .css instead of .attr works) and I am using I.E 8 and CSS (Not css3) if it helps.

Comment: To change CSS properties via jQuery, you should use `$('#' + showThis).css({'background-color': '#063', 'height': '520px'})`, etc. In my opinion, it would be much easier to just toggle a class with the predefined styles.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some context, but `$(this)` and `$('#' + $(this).attr('id'))` should select the same element, no?

Comment: This is documented in the jQuery documentation. @JasonP You're right. Code redundancy there.

Comment: @Chad right but I need to have the !important tag. When I use the !important tag using .css it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2719875 in that case, I'd go with the class switching option. http://jsfiddle.net/3G6FT/

Comment: @Chad I can't switch or add classes, I have a huge script and long sctory short, if I change or add a class to showThis, then the code will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the best way of achieving what you want - jQuery has the `css` method as Chad says - but you want separate the `background-color` and `height` parts of your new style with a ; not a ,

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.attr()`  , you can use the `.css()` method passing an object with the desired styles as argument:

```
  $('#' + showThis).css({
       'background-color' : '#063',
       'height': '520px',
       'width': '20px'
    });
```

**edit:** Maybe this SO post will help you:

[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery)

Comment: hm yea but i need to use the !important tag so I don't think .css would work, I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: not sure if you came across this solution provided by someone on SO (see my edited post)

Answer (score 1):

You're making several mistakes here.

First, when you use `.attr('style', 'background-color: #063 !important, height: 520px');`, you shouldn't separate your properties with `,` but with `;`. **That is why it doesn't work.**

Secondly, you'd better use the solution provided by Chad to change your CSS, or add try to add a class?

Thirdly,

```
var showThis = $(this).attr('id'); // div0, div1, div2 etc.
$('#' + showThis) //...
```

doesn't make sense, as you take the `id` of your element to retrieve the element later. Just use `$(this)` instead of this.

### Edit

I don't know exactly why you need `!important`, but you certainly should avoid it, and prefer [CSS Precedence](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) over it. It's likely to solve your problem if you absolutely need to override another property.

Comment: right, the ',' instead of ';' solved it. I can't change / add classes, I have a huge script and long story short, if I add a class to #showThis then the code will break. Thirdly, yes $(this) should work, I just stored it in a variable because a couple lines below, I use another selector but later need to refer to the first $(this).

Comment: right, I am using the !important tag because there are external CSS files attached to it which I am not allowed to change. I am working for a company and they want to maintain a certain CSS for everything so I can't change the external CSS so then I started just using the !important tag, but yes CSS Precedence is certainly better.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the css() method instead

```
var showThis = $(this).attr('id'); // div0, div1, div2 etc.
$('#' + showThis).css({'backgroundColor': '#063', 'height': '520px'});
```

you dont need to use !important for inline styles

also background-color becomes backgroundColor

Comment: hm yea but i need to use the !important tag so I don't think .css would work, I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: when using !important, it should be added in your style sheet not on inline styles.. other wise you need to make your selector have more specificity - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Try with some **Css Class** like,

**CSS**

```
.active{
    background-color: #063 !important;
    height: 520px
}
```

**SCRIPT**

Use `$(this)` instead of`$('#' + showThis)` like,

```
$(this).addClass('active');//$(this) instead of $('#' + showThis)
```

Comment: That normally works but I have a huge script and long story short, if I add a class, the code will break.