# Adding !important with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I ran into an issue that I can't quite explain.

I wrote a function in in that function I was adding some inline styles to an element:

```
myEm.css({"margin":"0", "position":"fixed", "top":"50px", "left":"50px"});
```

It worked fine, however I noticed that this element already had some margin set in a CSS file and it used !important, so the only way I would be able to overwrite is by changing my code to

```
myEm.css({"margin":"0 !important", "position":"fixed", "top":"50px", "left":"50px"});
```

However, when I do that the entire margin attribute is dropped. Seems a bit odd, but after testing I suspect the exclamation mark is a culprit. Do I need to escape it somehow of use an encoded character? What am I missing?

Comment: You add a CSS style with `!important` and the CSS class to the element.

Comment: why setting manually the CSS ? why not create a new CSS rule and apply it when you want ?

Comment: You can probably see your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is to create a new CSS style with `margin !important` and add the CSS to the element.

**CSS:**

```
.zeroMargin { margin: 0 !important; }
```

and then in **JS:**

```
myEm.css({"position":"fixed", "top":"50px", "left":"50px"}).addClass('zeroMargin');
```

Alternatively, You can also do that entirely with JS using `cssText`

```
myEm.css("cssText", "margin:0 !important;position:fixed;top:50px;left:50px;"});
```

This is equivalent to setting the `style.cssText` property of that element. So you may not need an `!important` in that case..

To preserve you can use a function like below,

```js
$('#cssTest').css('cssText', function(i, v) {
  return this.style.cssText + ';border-color: blue !important;';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssTest" style="border: 1px solid red !important; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it with a javascript function that way:

```
myEm[0].style.setProperty('margin', '0', 'important');
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me when trying to change the CSS of a select2 element. (In my scenario, the command was of the format `$('span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single[aria-labelledby="select2-actual_element_id_goes_here-container"]')[0].style.setProperty('border-color', 'red', 'important');`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy trick I found on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css):

```
myEm.attr('style', function(i,s) { return s + 'margin: 0 !important;' });
```

Comment: This will not override other style set on margin attribute, you might end up with two values as margin attribute both set as important!

Comment: The question said that the original margin was set through a css file