# JS/JQUERY : Change css of generated tr's td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that allows me to generate td in a existing html table. 
This is the HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gentabl.css" /> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!--<form method="POST" action="InsertRes.php">-->
    <body>
        <?php include 'formInsertRes.php' ?>
        <button onclick="rdv()">Show more comments</button>
        <table id="calendar">
            <div class="header"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th onclick="prev()"><</th>
                    <th id="my" colspan="29"></th>
                    <th onclick="next()">></th>
                </tr>
            </div>
                <tr>
                    <th>HORAIRES</th>
                    <th id="0" colspan="5">LUNDI</th>
                    <th id="1" colspan="5">MARDI</th>
                    <th id="2" colspan="5">MERCREDI</th>
                    <th id="3" colspan="5">JEUDI</th>
                    <th id="4" colspan="5">VENDREDI</th>
                    <th id="5" colspan="5">SAMEDI</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th id="lun1">1</th><th id="lun2">2</th><th id="lun3">3</th><th id="lun4">4</th><th id="lun5">5</th>
                    <th id="mar1">1</th><th id="mar2">2</th><th id="mar3">3</th><th id="mar4">4</th><th id="mar5">5</th>
                    <th id="mer1">1</th><th id="mer2">2</th><th id="mer3">3</th><th id="mer4">4</th><th id="mer5">5</th>
                    <th id="jeu1">1</th><th id="jeu2">2</th><th id="jeu3">3</th><th id="jeu4">4</th><th id="jeu5">5</th>
                    <th id="ven1">1</th><th id="ven2">2</th><th id="ven3">3</th><th id="ven4">4</th><th id="ven5">5</th>
                    <th id="sam1">1</th><th id="sam2">2</th><th id="sam3">3</th><th id="sam4">4</th><th id="sam5">5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="8">8h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="9">9h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="10">10h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="11">11h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="12">12h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="13">13h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="14">14h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="15">15h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="16">16h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="17">17h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="18">18h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="19">19h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="20">20h</th></tr></tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</form>
</html>
```

test.js :

```
function tableCreate(){  
    $(".t").each(function () { //for each tbody avec nom de classe "t"
        $(this).find('tr').each (function() { //find l'unique tr écrit en dur dans le html
            for(var o = 0; o<30; o++){ //boucle qui insert des cellules dans le tr
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                this.appendChild(td);  
            } 
        });
        for(var p = 0; p<11;p++){ //boucle qui insert 11 nouvelles lignes à la suite de la précedente
            var tr = this.insertRow();
            for(var l = 1; l<31; l++){ //boucle qui insert des cellules dans les lignes nouvellement créer
                var td = document.createElement("td"); 
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("")); 
                tr.appendChild(td);      
            }
        }     
    });
}
```

I am trying to set css of my th's td in another function like that :

```
$('#8').find("td").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
```

However, it doesn't work. I have tried to just set my th css to see if it was a syntax error but it works fine with none generated elements

```
$('#8').css("backgroundColor", "yellow"); //works
```

It may be the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448038/jquery-css-doesnt-work) here. I tried their solutions but still can't set css ... 
Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `td` elements are not actually inside the `th` ones. What you're trying to do is finding `td` elements inside `th` ones (with id 8) and then setting the background color of those. This doesn't work.

What you need to do is to look for them inside the parent of `th` instead. Change your jQuery to the following:

```
$('#8').parent().find('td').css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
```

Your code (edited):

```js
function tableCreate(){  
    $(".t").each(function () { //for each tbody avec nom de classe "t"
        $(this).find('tr').each (function() { //find l'unique tr écrit en dur dans le html
            for(var o = 0; o<30; o++){ //boucle qui insert des cellules dans le tr
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                this.appendChild(td);  
            } 
        });
        for(var p = 0; p<11;p++){ //boucle qui insert 11 nouvelles lignes à la suite de la précedente
            var tr = this.insertRow();
            for(var l = 1; l<31; l++){ //boucle qui insert des cellules dans les lignes nouvellement créer
                var td = document.createElement("td"); 
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("")); 
                tr.appendChild(td);      
            }
        }     
    });
}

tableCreate();

$('#8').parent().find('td').css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gentabl.css" /> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!--<form method="POST" action="InsertRes.php">-->
    <body>
        <?php include 'formInsertRes.php' ?>
        <button onclick="rdv()">Show more comments</button>
        <table id="calendar">
            <div class="header"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th onclick="prev()"><</th>
                    <th id="my" colspan="29"></th>
                    <th onclick="next()">></th>
                </tr>
            </div>
                <tr>
                    <th>HORAIRES</th>
                    <th id="0" colspan="5">LUNDI</th>
                    <th id="1" colspan="5">MARDI</th>
                    <th id="2" colspan="5">MERCREDI</th>
                    <th id="3" colspan="5">JEUDI</th>
                    <th id="4" colspan="5">VENDREDI</th>
                    <th id="5" colspan="5">SAMEDI</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th id="lun1">1</th><th id="lun2">2</th><th id="lun3">3</th><th id="lun4">4</th><th id="lun5">5</th>
                    <th id="mar1">1</th><th id="mar2">2</th><th id="mar3">3</th><th id="mar4">4</th><th id="mar5">5</th>
                    <th id="mer1">1</th><th id="mer2">2</th><th id="mer3">3</th><th id="mer4">4</th><th id="mer5">5</th>
                    <th id="jeu1">1</th><th id="jeu2">2</th><th id="jeu3">3</th><th id="jeu4">4</th><th id="jeu5">5</th>
                    <th id="ven1">1</th><th id="ven2">2</th><th id="ven3">3</th><th id="ven4">4</th><th id="ven5">5</th>
                    <th id="sam1">1</th><th id="sam2">2</th><th id="sam3">3</th><th id="sam4">4</th><th id="sam5">5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="8">8h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="9">9h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="10">10h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="11">11h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="12">12h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="13">13h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="14">14h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="15">15h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="16">16h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="17">17h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="18">18h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="19">19h</th></tr></tbody>
                <tbody class="t"><tr class="h"><th rowspan="12" id="20">20h</th></tr></tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `</div>` should appear after your `</thead>`. Although this is irrelevant because a div can't be a direct child of a table. You also have `th` tags as direct children of `th` tags. These are both invalid HTML markup.

`$('#8').find("td").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");` won't work because `#8` is the ID of the `th`. The `.find` function select elements inside of a parent. So with that jQuery you are looking for a `td` element inside of a `th` element, which will select nothing in your case.