# Is it possible to append a css property with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

**Question :** Is there any way to append some css property using jquery without changing/overriding the previous value?

**For example** : if i want to add `!important` to all of the color properties applied by my style sheet. Would it be possible to do it with jquery? rather than going through each of the css file and putting a `!important` in front of every color property?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: @SridharR, thank you for your reply. I have studied it already before opening a question. The link you have provided actually mentions it that you need to put some value of the property first and then adding !important after it. What i want is to append !important where ever there is a color property applied.

Comment: can you explain us why are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: If you "need" `!important` applied to _all_ colour properties in your style sheet you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: wouldn't applying !important to all colour have the same effect as applying it to none?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the all selector `('*')` together with `each()`, to loop through each element and apply the `!important` rule.

```
$('*').each(function(){
    var c = $(this).css('color');

    $(this).attr('style', 'color: '+c+' !important;');       
});
```

But be careful, the `attr` method will unset any previously set in-line style rules.  You need to execute the above solution on top of everything first.

See this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fs3zq/).

Comment: this would create an empty color attribute with the !important flag on all elements that did not have a color to begin with.. shouldn't you at least check if c isn't empty?

Comment: There is no empty color attribute, if you did not set the `color` the browser will render it with the default `rgb(0, 0, 0)`, even up to the `html` level. So you cannot just check `if(c == '')` but rather `if(c == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')`.