# jQuery for displaying a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the style of a textbox which has the attribute `display:none;`

I have another textbox and when I click inside the textbox, I should have the other one's css to be changed to `display:inline-block!important;`

```
<input type="text" id="linkField" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter the link to track">
<input type="text" id="emailField" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter the Email" style="display:none!important">
<input type="button" class="btn-success btn lightGreen" value="SHORTEN & TRACK">
```

I tried something like this but it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#linkField').click(function() {
        $("#emailField").css({"display": "inline-block!important"});
    }); 
});
```

Can anyone help me? Please let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .show() instead of fiddling with inline css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#linkField').click(function() {
        $("#emailField").show();
    }); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ub5u/)

Answer (score 1):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/awladnas/a6NJk/614/

You were really close to your solution. 
Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#linkField').click(function() {

        $("#emailField").css('display','block');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to set the display attribute:

```
$("#emailField").css("cssText", "display: inline-block !important");
```

I found this in the following post: [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery)