# Why can't I change the line-height CSS property using .css() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the line-height property with jQuery using this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $('h1').css({
        'top': Math.floor(windowWidth * 0.0964) + 'px',
        'left': Math.floor(windowWidth * 0.0872) + 'px',
        'line-height': '0.9em !important'
    });
});
```

If I use the inspector and check the element style, I can see the top and left property but not the line-height, can someone explain to me what's wrong?

And here's the jsFiddle I made just to be sure I'm not crazy!
http://jsfiddle.net/p4DU6/4/

Tested it in FF, Chrome, IE8 and IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `!important`. There's no need for that.

It works for me if you remove that.

Your inline style will have higher [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than anything else in your CSS anyway, so no need to use `!important`.

Comment: Beat me to it! This is the correct answer. Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4DU6/6/

Comment: Do note that non-`!important` inline styles are overridden by `!important` stylesheet styles.

Comment: If someone needs to use `!important` in inline styles, their code is an absolute mess.

Comment: As @ajp15243 said, I have a `!important` stylesheet style on the `h1` but I will create a new class to address this.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed here: [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery)

The problem seems to be the !important statement. There is a bug report for jquery and a way to work around it, namely creating new classes and combining them:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173