# $(this).css not changing css values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
$('#downvotebutton').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red !important');
    console.log('foo');
    //more
```

When downvotebutton is clicked, 'foo' is returned to the console but the background-color doesn't change. jQuery is linked to and works elsewhere in the page. what could possibly be the cause?

Comment: can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: do you want to change the background of the button or the body or some div?

Comment: i want to change background-color of the button, which is a div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hjea4/1/

Comment: Their might be a condition that this is not pointing your target element.

Comment: Please see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really need `!important`? Following will work:

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or if you need `!important`:

```
$(this).css("cssText", "background-color: red !important;");
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `!important` statement using jQuery  `css()` method.

You could use:

```
$(this).attr('style', function(_, rules) { 
     var newval = rules?rules:"";return newval + ';background-color: red !important;' 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead since `css()` cannot set `!important` property:

```
$('#downvotebutton').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('style', 'background-color: red !important');
    console.log('foo');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t2QFX/)**

Comment: This solved the problem. I'm still puzzled over why $(this).css() didn't work though

Comment: @user3324865 it works, but other way, check my answer

Comment: You can set important with the css method, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$(docuemnt).ready(function(){
$('#downvotebutton').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    console.log('color changed');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead. `.css` doesn't support `!important`.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173

Answer (score 1):

Actually you **can** use !important with the .css() method.

cssText allows you to pass over a 3rd arguement, in this case !important

```
$('#downvotebutton').css("cssText", "background-color: red !important;");
```

Hope this helps!