# How to add !important in position:absolute using jQuery.css() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I know this is very silly question but I am stuck . I have been trying to add the `position:absolute !important` using `JQUERY` function `.CSS()` but I found out that it is not happening .

my **script** is something like this .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var winSize = $('#outerPage').height();
    alert(winSize);
     setTimeout(function () {
    //$('#at4m-mobile-container').addClass('bottom');
    $('body div.at4m-dock').css("top",winSize);
    $('body div.at4m-dock').css({"position":"absolute","font-size":"200% !important"});
    $('body div.at4m-dock-toggle').css("top",winSize);
    }, 7500);  

});
```

Please give me some suggestion

Thanks and regards

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/apply-important-css-style-using-jquery

Seems to have quite a few different answers for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is not understanding the `!important` attribute.

You can use `attr()`

Try:

```
 $('body div.at4m-dock').attr('style', 'font-size: 200% !important;position:absolute !important;');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7j5Jc/)

Comment: I am accepting your answer because :)

Answer (score 1):

Use as, as per my understanding you can not use as `"font-size":"200% !important"` in `%`

```
  $('body div.at4m-dock').css({"position":"absolute!important","font-size":"22px !important"});
```

Comment: @DownVoter please provide reason

Comment: I am not the DownVoter but this will not work. jQuery can not understand !important as a rule. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5Jc/1/

Comment: Yes I looked into the fiddle it does not understand !important . and regarding the down vote no rpoblem i upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`!important` is not supported by jQuery.

Also `.css()` function add inline style so you don't need `!important`. So you should simply remove it.