# JQuery variable received via dropdown not applying css

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I understand that it is possible to use a variable as the css property to be applied by jQuery (using `.css('property',variable)`) but for some reason the variable that is successfully got is not being put into the css.

Here is the JQuery code that I have:

```
    $('#color-scheme').change(function(){
      var colorScheme = $('#color-scheme').val();
      $('.wppw-title-font-color').css('color','');
      $('.wppw-background-color').css('background-color','');
      $('.wppw-title-font-color').css('color',colorScheme);
      $('.wppw-background-color').css('background-color',colorScheme);
      console.log(colorScheme);
    });
```

A demo of the project I am currently doing can be found here:
http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/ipsHu

I want the user to be able to change the styles of my fancybox via the menu that I have created. (I'd only want to be using JQuery to do this open to suggestions on changes that I can do on the menu as well to more easily get the desired result.)

Thanks!

Thanks for the replies, turns out I was a dunce and didn't remove the !important on the css properties, my bad!

Comment: What value does `colorScheme` have?

Comment: these lines are not required $('.wppw-title-font-color').css('color','');
      $('.wppw-background-color').css('background-color','');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because of the `!important` rules attached to the things you are trying to change. Try this instead:

```
$('#color-scheme').change(function(){
  var colorScheme = $(this).val();
  $('.wppw-title-font-color').css('cssText', 'color: ' + colorScheme + ' !important;');
  $('.wppw-background-color').css('cssText', 'background-color: ' + colorScheme + ' !important;');
  console.log(colorScheme);
});
```

There are also other ways to do this, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css).

**EDIT:**
To make this work for your font selection, you need to remove the semi-colons (`;`) from the end of the values in the select.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I thought I had removed the importants prior to making this change, but it appears I hadn't!

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be in your css you have given color as important.

.wppw-title-font-color:hover {color: #660000 !important;}

try remove !important;
.wppw-title-font-color:hover {color: #660000}

OR
in you jquery try like this.

```
$('#color-scheme').change(function(){
  var colorScheme = $('#color-scheme').val() +" !important";
  $('.wppw-title-font-color').css('color','');
  $('.wppw-background-color').css('background-color','');
  $('.wppw-title-font-color').css('color',colorScheme);
  $('.wppw-background-color').css('background-color',colorScheme);
  console.log(colorScheme);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I thought I had removed the importants prior to making this change, but it appears I hadn't!