# multiple attr() only work partially in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to do css !important so I use attr() like below. The problem is only the right work but not the top. At first I suspect in my other part of css there is an !important that override it, but there's none.

```
$('#submitted').attr({'style':'top: 0 !important', 'style':'right: 0 !important'});
```

I also tried like this, same problem occur, only right work. why?

```
$('#submitted').attr('style','top: 0 !important');
$('#submitted').attr('style','right: 0 !important');
```

Comment: have u tried to use .css()?

Comment: @HendraLim [jQuery doesn't support `!important` in `.css()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2655925/1883647)

Comment: You are probably overwriting the first 'style' attribute with the second.  Try .attr({'style':'top: 0 !important; right: 0 !important'});

Answer (score 2):

Because you're setting the style property twice. It's like saying:

```
style="foo";
style="bar";
```

since, as far as jquery is concerned, this is just a variable. It won't magically add ";" for you. On the other hand *you* can. Just do this:

```
$('#submitted').attr('style','top: 0 !important; right: 0 !important');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.css()` as shown :

```
$('#submitted').css('top','0 !important');
$('#submitted').css('right','0 !important');
```