# How to remove z-index: 1000 !important of an element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

```
#admin-toolbar, #yoxview_popupWrap {
z-index: 500 !important;
```

}

How can i change the above one to

```
#admin-toolbar, #yoxview_popupWrap {
z-index: 1500 !important;
```

}
using jquery.

Comment: you cannot use !important in jquery .css()

Comment: this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#admin-toolbar").css("z-index","1500");
```

Adds it to an element, which has priority over `!important`

---

### Edit:

Since this does not work the same way with jQuery, and will not override an `!important` tag, what you can do is create a seperate style that proceeds & over-rides your current style.

```
#admin-toolbar, #yoxview_popupWrap {
z-index: 1500 !important;
}

#admin-toolbar.less, #yoxview_popupWrap.less {
z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

Here we just added a `.less` class to the same object, in case you would like to shrink the `z-index`

You would then apply the style `.less` to your element in jQuery like this:

```
$("#admin-toolbar").addClass("less")
```

and it will over-ride the existing value.

Comment: hope that also work but i am doing this addclass and removeclass to  rotate images inside these #admin-toolbar, #yoxview_popupWrap. if i change css for that class then image rotation will not get occur.

Comment: Don't see how else you're going to get this to work.