# jQuery Change css parameter if other element exists

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, exists

I have this `.bx-wrapper` element thats shown only on front page.

**If** it is **displayed** i need some **extra top margin** for my `#columns`.

This is the **code** I wrote so far :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($(".bx-wrapper").length) {
        $('#columns').css({ "margin-top": "90px !important" });
    }

 });
```

However it is not working.

I'm new to `jQuery` and `javaScript`.

I guess there is a little mistake somewhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the difference between Java and JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Comment: BTW, *Java is to JavaScript As Car Is To Carpet*

Comment: Java is to JavaScript As Ham Is To Hamster :D

Comment: did you import jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `!important` inside the setting of the css property. Because it is added as an inline style, it is overruling any CSS styles anyway.

So change:

```
$('#columns').css({ "margin-top": "90px !important" });
```

To:

```
$('#columns').css({ "margin-top": "90px" });
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you friend ! Works perfect now.