# How to work : document.getElementById("ElementName").style="display:block!important"

Tags: javascript, html

I have used:

```
document.getElementById("ElementName").style.display = 'block';
```

This is working. Now I would like to display the "ElementName" field on a button click.
But this was not working:

```
document.getElementById("ElementName").style="display:block!important"
```

Comment: Try with *space*: `display:block !important`

Comment: I tired this.It did not work for me.Is there any other way?

Comment: What does your code have to do with *" Now I would like to display the "ElementName" field on a button click."*?

Comment: See the Issue  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
document.getElementById("challenges").style.cssText += "display : block !important"
```

Comment: Modified the code to support tags having inline css's

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("ElementName").style.display = "block !important"

//or 

document.getElementById("ElementName").style.display = "hide !important"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this way... *(if you really want to do)* ?

**Try to add given class :**

```
var el = document.getElementById('ElementName');
el.className = el.className + ' block-important';
```

**and add this in your CSS file :**

```
.block-important {
   display: block!important;
}
```

But @torazaburo's answer says about using of `important` is correct

Comment: @torazaburo Idk his project, i answered as he asked :P