# On scroll jquery change html header tag background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

below is my simple code to change the background image of header tag but it is not working at the moment

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $("header").css("background", "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg2.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important");
    } 
    else {
        console.log('there');
        $("header").css("background", "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important");
    }
});
```

whats the matter in this code?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with it. Have you tried to debug at all? Checked the console for errors? Is 'there' appearing in the console? Help us to help you.

Comment: No not even an error u can check my website www.kreativestudio.ca no background at all

Comment: what is header ?? view-source and check how many occurrence of header you have in your html

Comment: Just change background-image to background and you should be ok

Comment: Still issue i changed it any one can check it www.kreativestudio.ca

Comment: Thanx Mr.Rory McCrossan for making this post Awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove !important from your jquery statement.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $("header").css("background", "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg2.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    } 
    else {
        $("header").css("background", "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    }
});
```

It's not necessary because its an inline style and jquery css can't handle it correctly.

If however you need it to be important, check out this question:
    [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Comment: Thanx Mr Ruben -J this Worked

Answer (score 0):

```
Syntax is wrong change background-image to background and add few css
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
header {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;    
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $("header").css("background", "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg2.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    } 
    else {
        $("header").css("background", "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg2.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/wkrnz92h/)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the applied CSS, in background-image you're only allowed to define the background image, "background" is the deal for you, try this (I also changed the code slightly but that's just a matter of taste ;)):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {

      $("body").css({
        "background": "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg2.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
      });
    } else {
        console.log("there");

      $("body").css({
        "background": "url(http://www.kreativestudio.ca/wp-content/themes/parasponsive/images/header_bg.png) repeat-x scroll 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: exactly but here you'll need background because not only the image url isset with the script