# How to change the css of div programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using div with some inline style and also i'm using a class to override the inline style. I need to change the border of the div while button click. I used the following code but it doesn't work?

**HtML Code:**

```
<div id="test2" class="test" style="height:30px; width:150px; background-color:red; border:1px solid green;"></div>
<button id="test1">Test</button>
```

**Class Style**

```
div.test{
    border:2px solid black !important;
    background-color:blue !important;
}
```

**Button Code**

```
$('#test1').click(function(){
    $('#test2').css('border','none !important');
});
```

**Demo**: For demo please click [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/r28h4vws/1/).

Please give some suggestions to change the css of the element.

Comment: you cannot use `!important` in `$(..).css()`

Comment: Now you understand why `!important` is frowned upon.

Comment: Related: [How to apply !important using .css()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kartikeya's comment that you cannot use `!important` in the `.css` method in jQuery, because the method applies the styles inline, the style will **not** be overwritten because of your use of `!important` here:

```
div.text {
    border:2px solid black !important;
}
```

I would suggest simply removing `!important` (excessive use of this is considered a bad practice). If you're not willing to do that, another possibility is to use the `.toggleClass` method to remove and add a method with your lack of border. But as I've stated, this is less preferable because `!important` should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

---

Also, it's worth noting that because of the box model and the way that elements take up space, when you remove the border, the element will physically shrink. To stop this occuring, instead of setting the border to `none`, set it to `transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

add another class for your style-change:

```
div.test_borderless{
    border:none !important;
    background-color:blue !important;
}
```

then use `removeClass()` and `addClass()` to swap the styles:

```
$('#test1').click(function(){
    $('#test2').removeClass("test").addClass("test_borderless");
});
```

**updated fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/r28h4vws/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove existing class `test` then add class `test2` that specify only `background-color`

```
div.test2{
    background-color:blue !important;
}

$('#test1').click(function(){
    $("#test2").removeClass("test").addClass("test2") 
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r28h4vws/5/)

Comment: I would suggest that better practice is to simply remove the `!important` declaration in the stylesheet instead of worrying about changing classes. This only further muddies code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the !Important from the jquery and from the css for border:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test2" class="test" style="height:30px; width:150px; background-color:red; border:1px solid green;"></div>
<button id="test1">Test</button>
```

**CSS**

```
div.test{
border:2px solid black;
background-color:blue !important;
```

}

**Javascript**

```
$('#test1').click(function(){
    $('#test2').css('border','none');
});
```

Here is a working update: http://jsfiddle.net/r28h4vws/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var style = $("#test2").attr("style");
    //Write code to remove css of border here like following.
    style = style.replace("border:1px solid green;","");
    $("#test2").attr("style", style+"border:none !important;");
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `str_replace` method in JavaScript. it should be `style.replace(...)`.