# jQuery if css = value then

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I am using jQuery to add a class of .display-product-noms to a div upon a certain menu item being hovered over. Once this triggers I then want a banner to appear but only if the previous class has been added to a div so i tried using the following:

```
if ($('.display-product-noms').css('left') === '16.4em!important') {
    $('.nav-banner').css( "left", "41em!important" );
}
```

but nothing happens, the banner stays out of view with its original value of left: -9999em;
Can anyone shed some light on where i am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you need that? What is the real problem you need to solve? You chose bad way how to achieve that.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: I agree with panther. You are trying to achieve your goal in a very strange way. Have you tried just looking for the class name of the parents? Look at .parents(), .hasClass() methods.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jadpLq73/1/

```
if ($('.product').css('left') == '10px') {
    alert($('.product').css('left'))
    $('.otherProd').css( "left", "10px", 'important');
}
```

Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894528/3556874

```
div.style('color', 'blue', 'important');
```

this way you can define the `!important` priority

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!important` and use `pixel`, this is what `css` returns it is in px not in em so `16.4em = 262.399993896484px`

[image]

```js
console.log($('.display-product-noms').css('left'));
if ($('.display-product-noms').css('left') === '262.399993896484px') {
    alert("Chewbacca defense")
    //$('.nav-banner').css( "left", "41em!important" );
}
```

```css
.display-product-noms{
    left: 16.4em!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=display-product-noms />
```