# Fullcalendar font-size of events

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

When I change the `font-size` in the css like this:

```
.fc-event {
    font-size: .85em;}
```

The `font-size` looks perfect.

But when I change the `font-size` with jquery it does not work.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay'); //=> OK
  $(".fc table ").css("font-size", "1.40em");               //=> OK
  $('.fc-event').css('font-size', '1.85em !important'); //=> NOT OK
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 0.85); //=> OK
};
```

Other CSS settings do get changed. But the line `$('.fc-event').css('font-size', '1.85em !important');` does not.

UPDATE: This is all the code i used:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['email'])
{
    header("Location: login.php");//redirect to login page to secure the welcome page without login access.
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />

<link href='css/jquery.qtip.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

<script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>

<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='js/lang-all.js'></script>

<script src='js/jquery.qtip.js'></script>

<script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
<script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        //var username = $("input#username").val();
        //var password = $("input#password").val(); 
        var username = 'api_user';  //api gebruikersnaam
        var password = 'api_pass';  //api passwoord

        function make_base_auth(user, password) {
                                                var tok = user + ':' + password;
                                                var hash = btoa(tok);
                                                return "Basic " + hash;
                                                };

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        //Display settings
            //theme: true,
            //aspectRatio: 1, // verhouding hoogte breedte standaard is dit 1.35
            header: {
                    left: 'prev,next, today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaThreeDay,agendaDay' //ook mogelijk basicWeek, basicDay
                    },
            firstDay: 1, //Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.
            //hiddenDays: [ 0 ], //zondag verbergen [ 1, 3, 5 ] // hide Mondays, Wednesdays, and Fridays
            weekNumbers: true,
            businessHours: {
                            start: '7:00',  // a start time
                            end: '19:00',   // an end time
                            dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                            // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                            // (Monday-saturday in this example)
                            },
            views: {
                    agendaFourDay: {
                                    type: 'agenda',
                                    duration: { days: 4 },
                                    buttonText: '4 Dagen'
                                    },
                    agendaThreeDay: {
                                    type: 'agenda',
                                    duration: { days: 3 },
                                    buttonText: '3 dagen'
                                    }
                    },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',  //de calender opent standaard op dit overzicht month,agendaWeek,agendaThreeDay,agendaDay
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',       // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            lang: 'nl',

        //Calendar settings
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,   //allow "more" link when too many events

        //Events
            events: {
                    url:'events.php',
                    error: function() {
                                        alert('There was an error while fetching events! Check event settings, database connection and events.php');
                                        },
                    //color : 'green', 
                    },


            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                                                    $('.fc-event').css('font-size', '1.85em');
                                                    //element.qtip({content: event.title});
                                                },

        //Popup on event click
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                                alert('Afspraak details: \n' + calEvent.title + '\n' + '\n'
                                + 'Plaats: ' + calEvent.location  + '\n' + '\n'
                                + 'Omschrijving :' + calEvent.description  + '\n' + '\n'
                                //+ 'Van :' + calEvent.startgethours()>12?  + '\n' + '\n'
                                );
                                //alert('View: ' + view.name);
                                // change the border color just for fun
                                //$(this).css('background-color', 'deepskyblue'); //change color of selected item
                                },


        //Convert the allDay from string to boolean
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                                                        if (event.allDay === 'true')
                                                            {
                                                            event.allDay = true;
                                                            } 
                                                        else {
                                                            event.allDay = false;
                                                            }
                                                        },


        /*   
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                                                    element.qtip({
                                                                content: event.title
                                                                });
                                                   },
        */

        //Add event => alle velden toevoegen voor gebruikt kan worden
            /*
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                                        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                                        //var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                                        if (title) {
                                                    var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                                    var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                            url: 'http://www.data2info.be/_test/kalender/add_events.php',
                                                            data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
                                                            type: "POST",
                                                            success: function(json) {
                                                                                    alert('De afspraak is toegevoegd');
                                                                                    }
                                                            });
                                                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                                                        {
                                                                            title: title,
                                                                            start: start,
                                                                            end: end
                                                                            //allDay: allDay
                                                                        },
                                                                            true // make the event "stick"
                                                                        );
                                                    }
                                        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                                        $.ajax({
                                                url: 'navapi.php',
                                                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                                                type: "GET",
                                                //datatype: "json",
                                                statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "navapi.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
                                                                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
                                                                            },
                                                });         
                                        },
            */

        //Move event
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                                        var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                        var end = event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                        //Post changes - drag/drop event
                                        $.ajax({
                                                url: 'update_events.php',
                                                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                                                type: "POST",
                                                success: function(json) {   //refresh calendar on success
                                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                            //alert("Updated Successfully");
                                                                        },
                                                error: function(json)   {   //refresh calendar on error
                                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                        },
                                                statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "update_events.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                });
                                        //Post parameters tot api NAV
                                        $.ajax({
                                                url: 'navapi.php',
                                                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                                                type: "GET",
                                                //datatype: "json",
                                                statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "navapi.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
                                                                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
                                                                            },
                                                }); 
                                        },


        //Resize event
            eventResize: function(event) {
                                        var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                        var end = event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                        //Post changes - resize event
                                        $.ajax({
                                                url: 'update_events.php',
                                                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                                                type: "POST",
                                                success: function(json) {   //refresh calendar on success
                                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                            //alert("Updated Successfully");
                                                                        },
                                                error: function(json)   {   //refresh calendar on error
                                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                            //alert("Updated Successfully");
                                                                        },
                                                statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "update_events.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                });
                                        //Post parameters tot api NAV
                                        $.ajax({
                                                url: 'navapi.php',
                                                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                                                type: "GET",
                                                //datatype: "json",
                                                statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "navapi.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
                                                                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
                                                                            },
                                                });         
                                        },      
            }); //hier stopt the full cal





            $(".fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable").css("font-size", "2em");
            $(".fc-event-container").css("font-size", "2em");


        // afhankelijk van het gebruikte device
        /*
            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 0.85); //aanpassing aspect ratio
                //$("h1").css("color", "rgb(224, 68, 80)"); //debug info verander kleur van titel

                //$(".fc-centre ").css("font-size", "1.40em");
                //$('body .fc ').css('font-size', '3em');
                //$('.fc-event-content, .fc-event-time').css('font-size', '1.85em');


                $(".fc-event").css("font-size", "2em");
                };
            */

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3><a href="logout.php">Logout here</a> </h3>


<?php
    //echo "DEBUG INFO <br>";
    //echo $_SESSION['email']." dit is een email van de ingelogde gebruiker <br>";
    //echo $_SESSION['resource']." = resource ID <br>";
?>



<div id='Header'>
    <h1><?php echo "welkom " . $_SESSION['name']?></h1><br>
</div>


<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone see what I do wrong?

Kind regards,

Tim

Comment: Could you add a sample fiddle in order to help us to fix your issue?

Comment: You can't use `!important` like that in jQuery. See this answer for options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2655976/2572316

Comment: Hi, thx for your quick reply. I also tried it without the "!important".

Comment: @user3604268 have you tried `.addClass()` instead as in the answer I linked before?

Comment: @user3604268 did you find a solution now?

Comment: @RdrigoDela: No I havent found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the css rule without `!important`:

```
$('.fc-event').css('font-size', '1.85em');
```

Another way you could try to set the font-size are these classes (v2.x):

```
$('.fc-title').css('font-size', '1.85em');
$('.fc-time').css('font-size', '1.85em');
```

For version 1.x you need to use these classes:

```
$('.fc-event-content, .fc-event-time').css('font-size', '1.85em');
```

Be sure to apply this after your fullcalendar configuration!

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({...});
$('.fc-event-content, .fc-event-time, .fc-event-title').css('font-size', '1.85em');
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ra5x1Lu/2/

Comment: Hi, i tried these, but they don't affect the event text. These change the time column en calendar title.

Comment: Which version of fullcalendar are you using? It works fine with the latest version (2.2.7) for me. Version 1.x uses other classes btw. If you are not talking about the title and time, which text are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, i'm working with version 2.2.7. To be clear: when i change the class in the fullcalendar.css it workt fine. But when i change it in the jquery it does not. Other class changes in the jquery do work.

Comment: Do you apply it after your configuration? If not, that could be the problem.

Comment: Yes i did. The strange thing is that it is only the event text that does not change. When i use something like: $("h1").css("color", "rgb(224, 68, 80)"); it works perfect.

Comment: Well, I would recommend you to set up a fiddle which reproduces the strange behavior. Does my example work for you actually?

Comment: your exaple works. But i failed to mension that i use this in calenderDay view. That part does not work in your example

Comment: I updated the example. It works fine. In day view, too. What I changed is that the jQuery rule is applied on `eventRender`.

Answer (score 1):

In the fullcalendar.css file, find the .fc-event and edit the font size:

```
.fc-event {
    border: 1px solid #3a87ad; /* default BORDER color */
    background-color: #3a87ad; /* default BACKGROUND color */
    color: #fff;               /* default TEXT color */
    font-size: 1em;            /* EDIT HERE */
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.attr()` method instead of using `.css()` if you need the `!important` rule. Like this:

```
$('.fc-event').attr('style', 'font-size: 1.85em !important');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the class of the events by using the developer tools in Chrome(Ctrl+Shift+C). Then clicking on the events text, you can see which class the events are in. Then accordingly use the jQuery selector. I use v1 of fullcalendar and it shows the class to be 'fc-event-inner'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this style tag into your page

```
<style>
    .fc-event {
        font-size: 16px !important; //Your font size
    }

    .fc-day-grid-event .fc-content {
        white-space: normal !important;//to make event block more than a line
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ fullCalendar v5.9.0

use
`.fc-time, .fc-title { font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal;}`

if you cannot access `.fc-time` and `.fc-title` directly in your css, use shadow host `:host >>> .fc-time` and `:host >>> .fc-title`