# How can I set a text input's width to 0px with Bootstrap included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I want a 0 width input that expands into view, but it seems like Bootstrap's styling is not letting me do this without `!important`. But when I do mark it `!important`, I cannot seem to make it expand with jQuery's `.animate({width: "170px"}, 200)`.

Perhaps another alternative to make the box expand into view?

Comment: javascript sets inline styles, `!important` overrides inline styles, that's why that wont work. Set the styles inline instead on the input.

Comment: Use stronger/more specific selector than Bootstrap uses.

Comment: Oh yeah, @panther's solution is perfect! I am relatively new to web design and I didn't think of this. You can post it as an answer and I can mark it as correct if you wish.

Comment: "!important" as the name suggests overrides all other styles and should be used very carefully else you could have unexpected results as you are having... Perhaps post a fiddle, but try adding another class to that element and then edit that class in animate

Comment: Btw you can remove `!important` before animating.

Comment: How do I change `!important` from jQuery?

Comment: @Antrikshy: I posted there as an answer, added there example. It's better and clearer solution than using `important`, forget on it.

Comment: I agree. Can't believe I didn't think of it. I'm still curious how I can toggle `!important` from JavaScript.

Comment: @Antrikshy: as I know jQuery (it's just a JavaScript), it's not possible to change rules which are written in CSS file.  JavaScript can't change CSS files content.

Comment: @Antrikshy see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stronger/more specific selector than Bootstrap uses.

Bootstrap uses a lot of classes in their CSS, so stronger selector will be each one with ID. eg. `#content .col-md-6 .col-md-4` is stronger than `.col-md-6 .col-md-4` etc.