# Why I can't set this CSS settings using the JQuery style() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some problem with this JQuery script (on a project that use **Jquery-1.9.1.min.js**):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("thead.opening").click(function () {

        var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        alert("INTO second function, chrome: " + is_chrome);

        $(this).next().css('width', '10000000em');
        $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');

        //$(this).next().css('display', is_chrome ? 'table-row-group' : 'table-row-group');

        //alert($(this).next().css('display'));
    });
});
```

This script simply set a CSS style to the **tbody** element related to the clicked **thead** element, and do it in this way:

```
$(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
```

It works but I have to set also the **!important** for this CSS property but if I do in this way it can't work:

```
$(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group !important');
```

So searching online I found this post on StackOverflow: [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

So, into the previous script, I tryed to use:

```
$(this).next().style('width', '10000000em', 'important');
$(this).next().style('display', 'table-row-group', 'important');
```

instead:

```
$(this).next().css('width', '10000000em');
$(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
```

But the problem is that I obtain this wrong result:

```
<tbody class="expanded" style="display: block; width: 1e+7em;">
```

So it seems that the **width** property is correctly setted but the **display** property not (infact it is setted on **block** and not on **table-row-group**)

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Do you have any demo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest creating a class like the following:

CSS

```
.forceDisplay { display: table-row-group !important; }
```

Then use jQuery's addClass() method to apply the !important declaration.

```
$('#element').addClass('forceDisplay');
```

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with your markup so others can see what might be causing the issue here.