# How to add 'important' to zIndex

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I have conflict between some add-ons on my site. Using Firebug, I noticed that if I add "!important" to the z-index I can avoid the conflict.

but the z-index value is set using JavaScript and not CSS

so how do I add "!important" to the following JS code:

```
this.menu = $("<ul>")
   .addClass("ui-autocomplete")
   .appendTo(this.document.find(this.options.appendTo || "body")[0])
   .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1)  // !! <- here // !!
   .hide()
   .data("menu");
```

EDIT: from the proposed answer [[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css) ] I understand that I need to add the following code -

```
if (XXX.style.setProperty) {  // IE 9- does not support...
    XXX.style.setProperty ("z-index", (this???.element.zIndex() + 1), "important");
  }
```

How do I add it: what is XXX in my case? and "this" ?

Edit 2: Since it became jQuery syntax question, I asked it with different tags in - [How to add 'if' to jQuery chain code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556847/how-to-add-if-to-jquery-chain-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply !important using .css()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Comment: The zIndex value is calculated from parent element : .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1)  so I cannot use CSS rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the answer in another thread - [How to add 'if' to jQuery chain code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556847/how-to-add-if-to-jquery-chain-code/30557946#comment49188395_30557946)

use -

```
.each(function() {
    this.style.cssText+= 'z-index: '+(parseInt($(this).css('z-index'))+1)+' !important';
  })
```

but after struggling with the code in several functions, I preferred to add a class and a rule to this class -

```
this.menu = $("<ul>")
  .addClass("ui-autocomplete")
  .addClass("ui-autocomplete-hover-header")  // !! added!
. . .

.ui-autocomplete.ui-autocomplete-hover-header {  
  z-index: 5004 !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i got this

```
this.menu = $("<ul>")
   .addClass("ui-autocomplete")
   .appendTo(this.document.find(this.options.appendTo || "body")[0])
//   .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1)  // !! <- here // !!
   .style.setProperty ("zIndex", zIndex()+1, "important");
   .hide()
   .data("menu");
```

Comment: Thanks. and how do i add the "if" to check for browser support?

Comment: `.style` is not a method of a jQuery collection, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using css to this? For example

```
this.menu = $('<ul class="high-zindex">')....
```

and then define `.high-zindex { z-index: 9999 !important }`

Answer (score -2):

Try this out.

```
.zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1 + '!important')
```

Comment: wont work since everything is converted to string if zindex is 99 it will become 991

Comment: This will work: .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() * 1 + 1 + '!important')