# How to add 'if' to jQuery chain code

Tags: jquery, z-index

I need to replace the 4th line in -

```
this.menu = $("<ul>")
   .addClass("ui-autocomplete")
   .appendTo(this.document.find(this.options.appendTo || "body")[0])
   .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1)  // !! <- here // !!
   .hide()
   .data("menu");
```

with the following code -

```
if (XXX.style.setProperty) {  // IE 9- does not support...
    XXX.style.setProperty ("z-index", (this???.element.zIndex() + 1), "important");
  }
```

- How do I merge this code?
- what is 'XXX' in my case?
- what is "this" ?

[relates to [How to add 'important' to zIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555958/how-to-add-important-to-zindex) ]

Comment: FYI, `z-index` is supported from IE6, albeit with a few issues

Comment: You can just set the property with `.css()`. Browsers that don't support it will just ignore it.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the totally invalid syntax, like there is `zIndex` function, and that you're calling `find` and `appendTo` on native DOM nodes etc.

Comment: setProperty() is not supported by elder browsers

Comment: .css() cannot add the needed 'important' priority

Comment: find() and appendTo() are from the original add-on. I just want to set zIndex with 'important' priority. I am not going to review all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
this.menu = $("<ul>")
  .addClass("ui-autocomplete")
  .appendTo(this.document.find(this.options.appendTo || "body")[0])
  .each(function() {
    this.style.cssText+= 'z-index: '+(parseInt($(this).css('z-index'))+1)+' !important';
  })
  .hide()
  .data("menu");
```

Comment: Thanks. Is [this.element] is equal to [$(this)] ? the new zIndex should be one higher than [this.element]

Comment: `this` by itself is the DOM element, which you can apply DOM methods and properties to such as `style`.   `$(this)` lets you call jQuery methods on the DOM element, but it does *not* allow you to access DOM methods and properties.

Comment: so, in the original code [ .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1) ] it says increment [b]my-self[b] zIndex.  not related to its [b]parent[b] zIndex?

Comment: Correct.  `this` within the `each()` method refers to the newly-created `ul` element.

Comment: If you could post a fiddle or link with all your code, I could confirm if this works.

Comment: Thanks. solved. Actually it solved the original question about css and important.  about adding 'if' to chain code the answer is - add the 'if' inside '.each(function() {'  . . .