# Accessing a div with a complex class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the code below, I've marked a `<div>` with "LINE BELOW". I need to set css background attribute but, no matter how I try the syntax in jQuery or JavaScript, it seems like it never recognizes the thing! Why won't it accept my CSS definition?

As a bonus explain to me how to override the existing background attribute that contains `!important` in it.

This is the approximate scheme of what I have in a target website:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="detailblock">
        <div class="tabsblock">
            <section class="editblock">
                <form id="target">
                    <div class="editblock-item">
                        <div class="input textarea">
                            <div class="editor_box">
                                //LINE BELOW:
                                <div class="editor_ editor_text">
                                    //Something inside of div...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this and found during research and it didn't work:

```
jQuery(".editor_.editor_text").css("background","#000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%");
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I just tested and colored all divs in blue using css(). They all worked, except that particular one. But if I remove all divs using remove(), it will get removed with all divs. But if I remove that particular div using it's selector, it will not get removed!

Comment: Please show your jQuery/JavaScript code that seems to fail. It will help if we can reproduce the exact issue you are experiencing.

Comment: `jQuery(".editor_.editor_text").css("background","#000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%");` is what I tried first and found during research and it didn't work.

Comment: It [seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/2fws4k7s/). Can you show us an example in which it fails?

Comment: @showdev Unfortunately not, because on the target website it's only available for a signed up user. Also, I checked that if you add that attribute in style="" or in CSS properties in F12, it will work, but it's not a solution, of course.

Comment: I read your question again and it sounds like you might have an `!important` CSS definition somewhere that your jQuery method cannot overcome. Is that the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply !important using .css()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Comment: Hey people, thank you for your help. Update here: I just tested and colored all divs in blue using css(). They all worked, except that particular one. But if I remove all divs using remove(), it will get removed with all divs. But if I remove that particular div using it's selector, it will not get removed!

Answer (score 1):

you're not really selecting a `<div>` with a complex class name; you're trying to select a `<div>` with two class names assigned to it.  Your jQuery selector does not have to contain both of those class names; either will do, though of course you can specify both if you want.  Does `$("div.editor_")` select the element you want to change?  Does `$("div.editor_text")`?

Once you have figured out the proper selector, you can either call jQuery's `.css` method on the selected element:

`$(...).css("background", "blue");`

or you can edit the selected element's style property directly (as in, not through jQuery).  If you are attempting to override a CSS `!important` directive, I believe this is the method you must use:

`$(...)[0].style.setProperty("background", "blue", "important");`

(this works because two CSS rules are now marked as equally !important, and the order of application dictates that the one you're setting will win out.)

Comment: No, these didn't work as well (forgot to specify them), with both and without "div" in the beginning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the selector works, though I suppose it could depend on what version of jQuery you're using.  `$("div.editor_")[0].style.setProperty("background", "blue", "important");` selected the element and overrode the previous background style.  https://jsfiddle.net/9reevhdu/

Comment: @DanO Your last comment is the closest post to an answer. I suggest that you update your answer with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here there is an extra space between the two editor:

```
<div class="editor_ editor_text">
```

Works fine without the extra space in this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yutzjbjr/

**edit**

I see now that there are two classes involved. You should include your jquery **in** the question.

However still works fine with two classes: http://jsfiddle.net/yutzjbjr/1/

Can you maybe read the console?

Comment: I wish it was, but it's not, I specified it as is. It's intended to be like that and I'm not able to select it. I still tried it though in case a miracle occurs - it didn't.