# Making font strong to normal using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `div` like the following:

<`div id="div1" ><strong>some text</strong></div>`

I want to make the font normal using jquery. I tried as follows:

```
$("#div1").css("font-weight", "normal !important");
```

But it is not working!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to select the `<strong>` not the div.

```js
$("#div1 strong").css("font-weight", "normal");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"><strong>some text</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: This could solve the problem, but if you want to do it the correct way, you should remove the <strong> attribute.

Comment: True but I'm addressing the problem supplied by the OP. Your comment should really be on the question...not this answer...but thanks.

Comment: You indeed solved the problem. But if you want to do this using "proper code" you should remove the <strong> element instead.

Comment: @Joost - I nearly agree ;-) I'd say if there's an element there (`<strong>` is used), there might be other reasons. But since an emphasis is not a "static" requirement of this element (hence "normalization" of the font weight) perhaps a different element type should be used (`<span>` is an obvious choice here)

Comment: The `strong` or the HTML might unchangeable for whatever reason

Comment: @Paulie_D - Maybe, but that's poor HTML then. Nowadays HTML should be representative of content, not appearance.

Comment: I gave you an +1 for solving. I agree, there might be a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

What your code does is set the font weight for the content of the `<div>`, and using `!important` can help override other css settings to the same element.

There are 2 problems though:

One problem is that the content (text...) is inside a nested element, and that has it's own style. You can either set the style of the nested element, or remove it altogether.

The other is that [`!important` doesn't work inside `$().css()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css). So you should try to get rid of it if you can (to avoid complex solutions).

Assuming you need an element to wrap the text (for whatever reason), I'd suggest replacing it with a more appropriate descriptive element (or rather, less descriptive in this case) and play with the style as needed:

```js
$("#myText").css("font-weight", "normal");
```

```css
#myText {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" ><span id="myText">some text</span></div>
```