# Override css using jquery not working for addthis

Tags: jquery, html, css, addthis

I need to override `addthis` css property it is not working when i add `!important` to it example

**Works**

```
$("#at4-scc").css("opacity", "1");
$("#at4-scc").css("visibility", "visible");
```

**Result** `style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;"`

```
<div id="at4-scc" class="at-share-close-control ats-transparent at4-show at4-hide-content" title="Hide" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
   <div class="at4-arrow at-left">Hide</div>
</div>
```

**Doesn't Works**

```
$("#at4-scc").css("opacity", "1 !important");
$("#at4-scc").css("visibility", "visible !important");
```

**Result** `style=""`

```
<div id="at4-scc" class="at-share-close-control ats-transparent at4-show at4-hide-content" title="Hide" style="">
   <div class="at4-arrow at-left">Hide</div>
</div>
```

Not sure why it doesnt work. I have to override default css as that has `!important` property with it

Default css

```
    .at4-hide, .at4-hide-content {
      opacity: 0 !important;
    }
.at4-hide-content {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I also tried below this add only the last css not both.

```
$('#at4-scc').attr('style', 'opacity: 1 !important');
$('#at4-scc').attr('style', 'visibility: visible !important');
```

Comment: make those styles as a class in your `css` and use `$().addClass()` instead

Comment: This may help you [how-to-apply-important-using-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css).

Comment: Using `!important` is an anti-pattern as it negates the foundational utility of css (the cascading part). At all costs, do not use !important as it creates quite a code smell that must be "remembered"/"parsed for" by team members when css things go awry.

Answer (score 0):

instaed overriding remove previous class 
like

```
$('#at4-scc').removeClass('at4-hide');
$('#at4-scc').removeClass('at4-hide-content');
```

then add

```
$("#at4-scc").css({"opacity":"1","visibility":"visible"});
```

Comment: My question is it breaks when i add` !important`

Answer (score 0):

please put new css in a class and add this class on `addthis`, This will work.

CSS

```
.newClass{"opacity":"1";"visibility":"visible";}
```

Jquery

```
$('#at4-scc').removeClass('at4-hide');
$('#at4-scc').removeClass('at4-hide-content');
$("#at4-scc").addClass('newClass');
```