# position fixed is set as position static

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know why, but when I try to set the `position:fixed` in jquery:

```
 $('#footer').css('cssText', 'position:fixed !important;');
```

for my footer, I get on the page this result:

```
 <div id="footer" style="position: static;">
    ...
 </div>
```

I've checked in the Chrome console and there is no css loaded a part this setted through code. For some circumstance I can't set this in the .css file.
why happean this?

Comment: No man, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Comment: @Dillinger you should check this link: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I've already tried with this: $("#footer").css("position", "fixed"); and it's setted static

Comment: Yes, all of this as I said in the post.

Comment: Your question is unclear, it may be clear to you, but others are asking for clarification. Is the problem the fact that you can't override  a CSS style defined inline as an HTML attribute? If so, that's how it works, inline styles are override any  settings from a CSS file

Comment: I also set other property through code and all working fine, but the problem's only when I set the fixed position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way they do it, use this instead

```
$("#footer").css("position", "fixed");
```

And if this problem persists, try creating a class in **css** with `position:fixed !important;` like

```
.myClass{
       position:fixed !important;
 }
```

And add it to your footer using JQuery

```
$('#footer').addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: @Dillinger Try adding a class with the `position:fixed;` to your footer instead, check edit.

Comment: @Dillinger: That seems to be a different approach, not fixing the original problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#footer').css('position', 'fixed');
```

And consider where you are fixing it, with a top, left, right, or bottom css rule too.