# Set width value dynamically using css property in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to overlay an existing div with a new dynamically created div with same dimensions. I try to set the height and width for the new div dynamically using the existing divs height and width.
I am getting the dimensions of the existing div in **divSize** array and I pass the same to the **generateDiv** function

Upon inspecting the element i find that It does not add the height and width property values to the CSS. What am I doing wrong here Am I missing something any help would be much appreciated
May code is as follows:

```
function generateDiv(divSize, divContent, object) {
            $('<div class="divOverlay">' + divContent + '</div>').css({
                'width': divSize[0] + 'px !important',
                'height': divSize[1] + 'px !important',
                'background-color': '#ddd',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'color': '#56D9C9',
                'margin':'7px 7px 7px 0px',
                'zIndex': '100'
            }).appendTo($("#" + object).css("position", "relative"))

        }
```

Comment: Please append html first then add css from jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
function generateDiv(divSize, divContent, object) {
        $('<div>').addClass("divOverlay").html(divContent).css({
            'width': divSize[0] + 'px',
            'height': divSize[1] + 'px',
            'background-color': '#ddd',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'color': '#56D9C9',
            'margin':'7px 7px 7px 0px',
            'zIndex': '100'
        }).appendTo($("#" + object).css("position", "relative"))

    }
```

Comment: Hi Av. Can you please explain how is it working. Its picking up the height and width property values but as soon as I include important it fails to load them. Why is this difference in this behaviour.

Comment: You need to use style function. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Comment: Or another option is make a class with !important value and addClass.

Comment: Ah, I mostly just cleaned your code so it could be easier for jQuery to understand. The `!important` part fails because it's not part of a css value, but is the priority of that style. So when you try to pass it as part of the value argument the base javascript functions below jQuery can't parse it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, @ParthTrivedi 's link give better explanation than I do. Thanks :)

Comment: @AvAvt yes.Link give better explanation for ! important problem with css function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First append html then apply css.

```
function generateDiv(divSize, divContent, object) {
            $('<div class="divOverlay">' + divContent + '</div>').appendTo($("#" + object).css("position", "relative")).css({
                'width': divSize[0] + 'px !important',
                'height': divSize[1] + 'px !important',
                'background-color': '#ddd',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'color': '#56D9C9',
                'margin':'7px 7px 7px 0px',
                'zIndex': '100'
            })

        }
```

Comment: Tried this approach It doesn't solve the issue. Can you please explain how this order will help in picking up the height and width attribute.

Comment: You are only facing problem with "width" and "height" only? Other css works?

Comment: Try to console(divSize[0]) & console(divSize[1]). Are you getting value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div />").attr('style', 'width: 100px !important;');
```

This will work