# In Jquery .css({height: "300px !important"}) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

in JQuery I am not able to set the Property value with `!important`

this is code  `.css({height: "300px !important"})`

Comment: user .css({height: "300px"}), instead of .css({height: "300px !important"})

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Answer (score 2):

Hello I found the Solution :

```
.css({height: "300px !important"})
```

to

```
.css("cssText", "height: 300px !important;");
```