# Trying to append "!important" to an inline style created with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an element that I need to be able to add '!important' to my inline style that I am dynamically creating using JS in order to override several CSS styles that exist in stylesheets developed by another person. Unfortunately, these stylesheets are used globally and this particular area has a slew of '!important's strung about through it that I cannot modify without risking altering previous headers that exist throughout the site.  I'm fairly rough in my JS skills, thus am having a rough go of figure this out.

Here is my current code snippet:

```
fixTextPosition: function()
{
  var width = $( window ).width();
    if (width > 1451){
      width = 1451;
    }
  var height = $( window ).height();
    if (height > 816){
      height = 816;
    }
  $("#banner-resize").css("minheight", height);
    if (height < 816){
      $("#banner-resize").css("minHeight", height - 1);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to append "!important" to  the "minHeight" value after it has gone through (height - 1) and cannot seem to figure out how to add the value as a string.

Thank you in advance to any helpers!

---

**Edited After Answers**

Thanks to all who gave some thoughts - I'll take what I learned from posting my question in here to make sure my next question is better phrased and given with more context. :)

The above question is referring to a global header element that has several "min-height = x!important" existing in global stylesheets that a previous developer created - meaning I don't get to play as freely as I would like. I was able to work around it by creating a new class that contains all of the previous positioning styles and the new "min-height=x" sans '!important' which allowed me to use the above JS as desired.

I'm still curious to see if there is a more simple JS workaround to append an '!important' to an inline style as I don't really want to be creating new classes every time I run into this particular situation.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support `!important` as it really doesn't make sense to use it in inline styles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply !important using .css()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Comment: Element styles have the highest weight, so you shouldn't need the !important directive. If you find you do, you have made too much use of the directive in your stylesheets. Time to refactor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't the one who decided to use so many '!importants' :(   (I have a severe disdain for them...except in emails). The inherited values are coming from a global stylesheet that I cannot modify. I'll go back in and see if I can find another possible work-around for this issue through strictly css, which would be my ideal situation...

@MikeC - Thanks for the input! If I can't figure something out through a rejigger of classes and general css rules applied, I'll look deeper into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set any CSS style by jQuery, this style is added to DOM element style attribute.

For example, if you have element:

```
<p class="test" id="testId">
```

and you will add style by jQuery:

```
$(".test").css("min-height", 30);
```

In your DOM you will now have:

```
<p class="test" id="testId" style="min-height: 30px">
```

And styles from style attribute overwrite styles from included CSS file, unless you use !impotrant in CSS file.

Just don't use !important in CSS. And when you set new style value by jQuery it will automaticly overwrite style value.

---

How to set min-height style attribute without jQuery:

by 'id' attribute:

```
document.getElementById("testId").style.minHeight = "30px";
```

by 'class' attribute:

```
document.querySelector(".test").style.minHeight = "30px";
```

querySelector - gets first element with class 'test'

```
var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
for (var i = 0, len = elementsList.length; i < len; i++) {
  elementsList[i].style.minHeight = "30px";
}
```

query selectors are available in all modern browsers, from IE8.
But in IE8 you can't use CSS3 selectors

Comment: Do you have a non-jQuery version?

Comment: I ended up going through and creating new classes in order to detach this particular element from the '!important' issues that were existing in the stylesheets that were controlling the height previously.

Comment: cont'd - 

The content-block is a Wistia Video Embed that is needing to resize and retain the aspect-ratio with the browser resize, and find the browser width/height on load, meaning JS is needed to find the w&h of the browser to adjust the content as it scales. 

For now I have accomplished what I needed by just creating a new style (per previous suggestions). I wish I could go find the developer who decided to use so many '!important's...

Answer (score 0):

*I assume this is what you are trying to do:*

```
fixTextPosition: function(){
 var width = $( window ).width();
 if (width > 1451){
  width = 1451;
 }
 var height = $( window ).height();
 if (height > 816){
  height = 816;
 }

 if (height < 816){
  $("#banner-resize").css("min-height", height - 1);
 }
 else{
  $("#banner-resize").css("min-height", height);
 }
}
```

*If the above doesn't work, try this:*

```
 fixTextPosition: function(){
 var width = $( window ).width();
 if (width > 1451){
  width = 1451;
 }
 var height = $( window ).height();
 if (height > 816){
  height = 816;
 }

 if (height < 816){
  var ht = height - 1;
  $("#banner-resize").css("min-height", ht+" !important");
 }
 else{
  $("#banner-resize").css("min-height", height+" !important");
 }
}
```

**Although I don't approve the above solution.**

*My opinion would be you use CSS,*

```
 $bannerResize = $('$banner-resize')
 if (height < 816){
  $bannerResize.addClass('height815');
  $bannerResize.removeClass('height816')
 }
 else{
  $bannerResize.addClass('height816');
  $bannerResize.removeClass('height815')
 }
}
```

and CSS for the above should be,

```
#banner-resize.height816{
  min-height:816px !important;
}
#banner-resize.height815{
  min-height:815px !important;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try. I'm still extremely fresh to Javascript and honestly am a bit over my head in troubleshooting this loop, so I look forward to playing with this bit of code.

Comment: You're welcome, I have edited the code, you might want to check again.

Comment: In my opinion it's extremely ugly to have numbered CSS classes and hurts the maintainability of an application.

Comment: @user2867288 agreed! I have numbered it intentionally for better understanding of height and where it is applied. `#banner-resize.smallScreen` and `#banner-resize.largeScreen` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but there is a right answer to this question so let's put it here for the record.

```js
document.getElementById('banner-resize').style.setProperty('min-height', height, 'important');
```

What you were missing was the `priority` argument of the `setProperty` method of `CSSStyleDeclaration`.

> `priority` Optional
>
> A `DOMString` allowing the "important" CSS priority to be set. If not specified, treated as the empty string. The following values are accepted:
>
> - String value `"important"`
> - Keyword `undefined`
> - String empty value `""`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

However - as others have already pointed out and I'll just mention for the record -, unless something went terribly wrong, you should not need `!important` in element styles as these already have the highest specificity.