# Jquery css style not being applied

Tags: jquery, css

I feel like an idiot, but I'm going to ask anyway because I am going crazy.

I have an image element on the page that I need to dynamically change the padding on based on a users selection. The only way to do so it to amend the style tag that is on this image since there could be multiple of the page.

To do so I am grabbing the image and then adding a `.css()` to it.

```
var currentImg = $(this.$el.find('.form_control').find('img'));
var imagePadding = props ? JSON.parse(props)['ImagePadding']: '';
```

and then

```
$(currentImg ).css("padding", imagePadding+'!important');
```

Seems simple. But it's not applying the css to the element.

The image is coming back looking like this

```
[<img class=​"mCS_img_loaded" src=​"img/​kiosk/​placeholder.jpg" style=​"font-family:​ Helvetica;​ border:​ 1px solid rgb(0, 65, 120)​;​ color:​ rgb(255, 255, 255)​;​ font-size:​ 1.25em;​ background-color:​ rgb(0, 93, 171)​;​">​]
```

My first thought was because it is coming back in an array (with the []) and tried to drill down using a `[0]` however that just threw type errors. So I am at a loss. I do not have any other padding styles coming back on it.

Comment: You have checked the selector is working fine?

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: @Varun Yes, all the sectors work fine. I'm using them in multiple other places, just here where it hates me.

Comment: @ochi, other than the type error I mentioned when I dig in using the [0] no I am not.

Comment: I do not have full understanding of jQuery so I do not have the complete answer but I can suggest a debugging method, 
Run the selector in the console and see if it will come back as the string you wanted, do the same with the `imagePadding` variable. Hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: You have not added a 'px' or '%' value in the padding ? @zazvorniki

Comment: If imagePadding does not have trialing space you have to add here : $(currentImg ).css("padding", imagePadding +' !important'); Notice space before !important

Comment: I suppose we would need to see the HTML as well to figure it out then... not enough info with the code above at this point - better yet, can you create a [mcve] in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @MegaXLR, I have done so in the console and everything comes back as it should. The Style is just not changing.

Comment: @Varun the em is within the varable imagePadding

Comment: @MaheshChavda, I have tried with a space and without. I have tried with and without the important as well.

Comment: @ochi The html is in my post above. It is the img tag that I posted.

Comment: Then you have to check is var currentImg = $(this.$el.find('.form_control').find('img')); is returning any object ? 
And what is the value of the variable imagePadding after this statement ? var imagePadding = props ? JSON.parse(props)['ImagePadding']: '';

Comment: Well but that's not *all* the HTML necessary because I cannot verify the first selector as I do not know how `.form_control` is in relation to the image - I suppose I can always *guess* but I'd rather be certain

Comment: Jquery css doesnt support important statement

Comment: @MaheshChavda the current image returns [<img class=​"mCS_img_loaded" src=​"img/​kiosk/​placeholder.jpg" style=​"font-family:​ Helvetica;​ border:​ 1px solid rgb(0, 65, 120)​;​ color:​ rgb(255, 255, 255)​;​ font-size:​ 1.25em;​ background-color:​ rgb(0, 93, 171)​;​">​] As stated above. Ans the value coming back from imagePadding is '.5em'

Comment: @ochi it's just a div surrounding the image.

Comment: @A.Wolff, that is why I have tried this with and without the important. Neither works.

Comment: You need to provide JS fiddle. Otherwise there will be endless discussion without any output.

Comment: @zazvorniki but if you use important statement somewhere else, inline style wont override it. First thing you should do is stopping using this statement any/every where, if you do.

Comment: I was able to reproduce some of it to make it work http://jsfiddle.net/wrkfwrb1/1/ - first I needed to remove `!important` as others pointed out - then there seems to be an issue with the parsing of the JSON (but that could be my format being wrong) - if I hard-code the padding value it works so (this would have been much easier if you just provided a fiddle to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(currentimage).attr('style','padding:'+vatiablename+'px');

Comment: This is doing exactly the same as the `.css` method. This is not useful information.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a space before `'!important'`, and also you should be sure that `imagePadding` contains `px` or `%`:

Also use `attr()` instead of `css()` to use `!important`.

### Edit 1:

```
$(currentImg ).attr('style', 'padding: ' + imagePaddgin + ' !important');
```

I hope that helps :D

(thanks @mhodges)

Comment: I have tried with and without a space before the important and neither have worked. I have also tried without the important all together. 

The variable imagePadding does have the em inside of it.

Comment: You cannot apply !important using jQuery's .css(). Here's an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/2655976/4987197

Comment: Thanks @mhodges, I fixed the answer ;)

Comment: But this removes any other inline style. See in link second answer to just append it instead

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, and that is the drawback of this solution. Adding a class with an !important style rule would be the preferred way to do this.

Comment: @mhodges ya but the best imho would be to investigate to why inline padding isnt applied