# Dynamically loaded CSS property want appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to add a border property using JavaScript to a div. I used this code.

```
var element = document.getElementById("divID");
element.style.border="3px #0099ff solid !important;"
```

But it want come. If I used,

```
element.style.display="none;"
```

It works. Also I tried the JQuery approach,

```
$("#divID").css("border","3px #0099ff solid !important;");
```

That is also not working. These are the CSS properties of the element. Can you tell me the reason for this?

[image]

One has marked this as duplicate. But the thing is I have used the code given by [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css/8894528#8894528),

```
var divID='#'+i + selectedEvent[0].percepticDrillDowns[j].id + '_div';
var div = $(divID);
div.style('border', '3px #0099ff solid');
```

But it gives an error saying style is not a function of div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8894528/6449750 check this

Comment: don't include `!important` or `;` ... important is not needed in an inline style, it always "wins"

Comment: Those thing want work. See my edit!