# adding css to div using JQuery but working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to run the following code, first remove class is working fine but the css is not, whats wrong with this, can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".testimonial_wrapper")
      .css({'margin-left':'auto !important', 'margin-right': 'auto !important'})
      .removeClass('fullwidth-box');
});
```

Comment: This looks like valid jQuery, what's working exactly and what's not working?

Comment: try using $ instead of JQuery.

Comment: $ would not work as its wordpress, but I dont think if this is the issue

Comment: You can't use `!important` ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2655976/2887133