# Override a 'left' style value using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the following is in my DOM:

```
<div
    id="itemEditor"
    class="quoteItemEditorView partType_MATERIAL editMode selectorEnabled" 
    style="left: -1px; right: 0px; width: auto; min-width: 480px; display: block;"
>
```

I am able to retrieve the element and replace the 'left' value however this is proving difficult. I have tried doing this through jquery and javascript via following methods but it wont over ride.

```
$("#itemEditor").css('style','left','400px !important');

document.getElementById("itemEditor").style.left="400px !important";

$("#itemEditor").css('style','left','400px');

document.getElementById("itemEditor").style.left="400px";
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this using jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$("#itemEditor").css('left','400px');
```

> jQuery `css()` gets the value of a computed style property for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for
>   every matched element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$("#itemEditor").css("left","400px");
```

No need for "style" and "!important".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Saumya's answer got upvotes because it won't work. You can't use `!important` with `.css()` and you don't need it anyway as jQuery's `.css()` function put the CSS inline. The following should suffice:

```
$("#itemEditor").css('left','400px');
```

And you should avoid using `!important` at all costs.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a3ruzgq9/)**

Comment: True this but just to note aside in a case [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/a3ruzgq9/1/) maybe someone wants to override an `!important` from the CSS. If it is really necessary and there is no other approach like add another class refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Comment: @DaniP Yes, there are rare, fringe cases where the only option is to use `!important` and that's about the only time it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to set position to absolute/relative like that:

```
 document.getElementById("itemEditor").style.position="relative";
```