# Toggle - jQuery function "on('show.bs.collapse', function (){})" doesn't react

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I was about to change the color of my links, that toggle some content with data-toggle="collapse", but it seems like the jQuery does not working properly.

jQuery:

```
$('#collapse_basic').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
$('#toggle_basic').css('color', '#856404 !important');
});
```

Trigger:

```
<a class="p-2 text-muted" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_basic" id="toggle_basic"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>&nbsp;Basic</a>
```

Content:

```
 <div class="collapse" id="collapse_basic">
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <p>...</p>
    </main>
</div>
```

I've also tried to change the  $("#collapse_basic").on... to  $("#toggle_basic").on... 
But nothing happens. Did i miss someting?

Best Regards

Comment: You never close your second ( and you never close {

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code missing.  You at least need to post the rest of the JS block so we can debug properly.

Comment: @xmastertje pardon, its my first post, had some trouble with the post form. I've updated the jQuery line. 

Thanks for the support, 
Best

Comment: @DougF Thats all what i can post according to this problem. If it would help, i can post the rest of the html container as well.

Comment: No I have enough here to debug.  It seems it's a problem with jquery not understanding how to apply important.  Check out the issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css.  If you take away the important and just use $('#toggle_basic').css('color', '#856404'); it does work.

Comment: @DougF worked perfectly, thanks!