# dynamically change css class property with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have div which transform property is getting changed by 3rd party Js application, what I want is to fix the transform property at some instance according to current transform property it have.

For that I need to add class with property `transform: current_transform!important` here with `!important` if any change in element style by 3rd party app will not be effective.

here I created a example snippet for better explanation

```js
//let this is third party app which is changing the paragraph width and html which code can't be manipulated
function changeHeight(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  $('p').html(y);
  $('p').css('width',x+"px");
}

// Here we need to write Js code so that any change in paragraph css will not be effective, if zoom is yes

$('[name="zoom"]').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).val()=='y'){
    // Here need to change to the .zoomed propery as widht: current_width!improtant so that paragraph width get fixed to lastly it have.
    
    $('p').addClass('zoomed');
  }
  else{
    $('p').removeClass('zoomed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .zoomed{
    width: 50px!important;
  }
 </style>
<label>zoom yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="zoom" value="y" />
<label>zoom no</label>
<input type="radio" name="zoom" value="n" checked/>

<div style="height:70px;border:1px solid #000000;" onmousemove="changeHeight(event)">
</div>
<p style="background-color:red;"></p>
```

This is only for example only, real scenario is different(about transform property and zoom) but the key is to change the class property dynamically so that change in style by third party is not effective.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Comment: it will change in element style, which will again changed by 3rd party app, how can it help.

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to re-define a css class?  If that's the case, there's nothing stopping you from writing js logic that inserts and manipulates a <style> tag on the page.

Comment: inserting a class with <style> tag will insert same class again and again, what I want is to manipulate the property of class instead of defining it again and again. Because this event occurs many many time

Comment: It will only insert again and again if you write it that way.  You could either change the existing one, or replace it entirely.  `<style>` tags can be selected just like any other element in the DOM.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y6cj9eou/  Dummy little example showing the concept.

Comment: @Taplar thanks a lot, you saved me.

Comment: I'm not sure fully I understand the question. **C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets are, well, cascading. If you want to override style rules from a class, apply the style rules directly to the element. [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode element style is getting changed by 3rd party js application, that's why I need to change the of CSS class property

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
//let this is third party app which is changing the paragraph width and html which code can't be manipulated
function changeHeight(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  $('p').html(y);
  $('p').css('width',x+"px");
}

// Here we need to write Js code so that any change in paragraph css will not be effective, if zoom is yes

      let styleOverride = document.querySelector('#styleOverride');
  
  if (!styleOverride) {
   styleOverride = document.createElement('style');
    styleOverride.id = 'styleOverride';
    document.body.appendChild(styleOverride);
  }
     styleOverride.innerHTML = '';
$('[name="zoom"]').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).val()=='y'){
    // Here need to change to the .zoomed propery as widht: current_width!improtant so that paragraph width get fixed to lastly it have.
    let wid= $('p').css('width')+"!important";
    styleOverride.innerHTML = `
 .zoomed{
     width: ${wid};
    }
  `;
    $('p').addClass('zoomed');
  }
  else{
    $('p').removeClass('zoomed');
  }
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .zoomed{
    width: 50px!important;
  }
 </style>
<label>zoom yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="zoom" value="y" />
<label>zoom no</label>
<input type="radio" name="zoom" value="n" checked/>

<div style="height:70px;border:1px solid #000000;" onmousemove="changeHeight(event)">
</div>
<p style="background-color:red;"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)**.

The idea is that the custom property `--last-p-width` is set to the element's `width` property value when you add the class `zoom`. Making it stay with the same value.

This post goes more into detail: https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/

#### CSS

```css
::root {
  --last-p-width: 50px;
}

.zoomed{
  width: var(--last-p-width) !important;
}
```

#### JS

```js
$('[name="zoom"]').on('change',function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'y') {
    $(":root").css("--last-p-width", $('p').css('width'));    // <-- HERE
    $('p').addClass('zoomed');
  }
  else {
    $('p').removeClass('zoomed');
  }
});
```

```js
function changeHeight(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  $('p').html(y);
  $('p').css('width',x+"px");
}

$('[name="zoom"]').on('change',function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'y') {
    $(":root").css("--last-p-width", $('p').css('width'));    // <-- HERE
    $('p').addClass('zoomed');
  }
  else {
    $('p').removeClass('zoomed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  ::root {
    --last-p-width: 50px;
  }
  
  .zoomed{
    width: var(--last-p-width) !important;
  }
 </style>
<label>zoom yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="zoom" value="y" />
<label>zoom no</label>
<input type="radio" name="zoom" value="n" checked/>

<div style="height:70px;border:1px solid #000000;" onmousemove="changeHeight(event)">
</div>
<p style="background-color:red;"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("body").mousemove(function(e) {
        window.mx = e.pageX;
        window.my = e.pageY;
        if (window.dragging) {
            // Calculate drag distance difference
            let diffX =
    window.drag_width =
parseInt((window.item_width + (window.mx - window.drag_x) * 1.75));
            let diffY =
   window.drag_height =
parseInt((window.item_height + (window.my - window.drag_y) * 1.75));
            // Absolute values ensure the item dimensions
            // never become negative
            $(window.dragging_target).css("width",
                Math.abs(diffX) + 'px');
            $(window.dragging_target).css("height",
                Math.abs(diffY) + 'px');
            $(window.dragging_target).css("lineHeight",
                Math.abs(diffY) + 'px');
            // Change cursor to either left-right or up-down arrow,
            // based on which direction the drag is the greatest
            if (diffX > diffY) {
                /* Optional, maybe a future feature... */
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: how this can help me ?