# Find all TD element inside TR and apply background color using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I want to apply background color to all td element inside TR tag based on div title for below structure

```
<TR>
<TD Class="ABC">
<div class="grid-content-cell-wrapper" title="Total US-MultiOutlet"><span style="display: inline-block; 
color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" class="runtime-list-item-wrap">Total US-MultiOutlet</span></div>
</TD>
<TD Class="ABC">
<div class="grid-content-cell-wrapper" title=""><span style="display: inline-block; color: rgb(204, 
204, 
204);" class="runtime-list-item-wrap"></span></div>
</td>
</TR>
<TR>
</TR>
```

i am trying using below code-

```
$("div[title='Total US-MultiOutlet']").closest('tr>td').css("background-color", "#FFA76C !important;");
$("div[title='Total US-MultiOutlet']").closest('tr td').css("background-color", "#FFA76C !important;");
```

Using above jquery it is applying background colour only to 1st TD not to 2nd TD

Comment: Your *selector* (as in "find all TD inside TR") works fine as long as you have valid HTML (add `<table>` to your code).  As you've asked 2 questions... the second doesn't work as it doesn't like `!important` in your css - remove that, add `<table>` and it works fine - ergo the "selector" (first question) is valid.

Comment: Your first question (find all TD) - is solved (in your snippet) as a typo - missing `<table>`

Comment: Your second question (apply colour) can be solved as a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655976/2181514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div[title='Total US-MultiOutlet']").closest('tr').find("td").css("background-color", "#FFA76C");
```

It is applying background color to all TDs present inside TR

Answer (score 0):

You do not need jquery or even javascript to do this. you can do this with straight CSS using the `attribute selector` in which elements that match the target will be styled. - in this case those with the title attribute that has the content of "Total US-MultiOutlet".

I would note however that although this approach works - it is VERY fragile and will fail if the title attribute content changes. You would be better served to find a more robust way of selecting the desired targets and adding a class that can be styled appropriately.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
}

td {
 border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
 padding: 0;
}

.grid-content-cell-wrapper {
 padding: 10px 16px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block; 
  color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}


.grid-content-cell-wrapper[title="Total US-MultiOutlet"] {
 background: #FFA76C;
}

.grid-content-cell-wrapper[title="Total US-MultiOutlet"] span{
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td Class="ABC">
      <div class="grid-content-cell-wrapper" 
      title="Total US-MultiOutlet">
      <span class="runtime-list-item-wrap">Total US-MultiOutlet</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td Class="ABC">
      <div class="grid-content-cell-wrapper" title="">
        <span class="runtime-list-item-wrap">Other content</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td Class="ABC">
      <div class="grid-content-cell-wrapper" 
      title="Total US-MultiOutlet">
      <span class="runtime-list-item-wrap">$100000</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td Class="ABC">
      <div class="grid-content-cell-wrapper" title="">
        <span class="runtime-list-item-wrap">Other content</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do not have permission to change CSS or HTML, so i am trying using jquery to apply css