# How to set !important css property in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

If i set css "padding-top" property to a value in variable (currentHeight), like here:

```
jQuery("#page-container").css("padding-top", currentHeight);
```

It works fine, and i get:

```
<div id="page-container" style="padding-top: 115px;">
...
```

But padding-top, has to be important like this:

```
<div id="page-container" style="padding-top: 115px!important;">
...
```

If i try to set important, like this:

```
jQuery('#page-container').css({'padding-top': + currentHeight + '!important'});
```

Than css property padding-top' is not given to element page-container like here:

```
<div id="page-container">
```

How to solove this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Comment: _"But padding-top, has to be important"_ - Why? jQuery adds the style directly on the element. There should be no need for `!important`

Comment: @Andreas the element style wouldn't apply if the stylesheet css is marked !important

Comment: @Rod911 Yes, but that's just another _"code smell"_. Why would you need `!important` in the first place?

Comment: https://vecta.io/blog/definitive-guide-to-css-styling-order

Comment: @Andreas Because template Stylesheet css is making important:
padding-top: 0!important;
In this case padding-top, because mobile menu is set to fix.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, since jQuery will not understand !important property.

My solution to this would be:

### Create a new CSS class

```
.paddingTop{
  padding-top: 115px !important;
}
```

### and use addClass() instead of css()

```
jQuery('#page-container').addClass('paddingTop');
```

```js
jQuery('#page-container').addClass('paddingTop');
```

```css
.paddingTop{
  padding-top: 115px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-container">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```