# change background color of div with jquery that has an !important tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a plugin that calls a .jsp that uses its own stylesheet hosted externally (it's a yelp embed - trying to manipulate the look of it). The one element I'm trying to change has an !important tag on it, and I can't seem to change it...

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.elementToChange').css({'background-color':'black'});​
</script>
```

to no avail. Ideas?

Comment: Show that part of HTML as well.

Comment: If `!important` has been declared in the external stylesheet that setting will override any other settings, regardless of the usual order of specificity, unless the later (more-specific) styles *also* declare `!important`. Incidentally, this question may be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style-using-javascript

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It looks like in more up-to-date versions of jQuery (at least 1.7.2 and higher) you can simply set the css:

```
$('#elementToChange').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/HmXXc/185/

In older versions of jQuery and Zepto you had to clear the css first:

```
// Clear the !important css
$('#elementToChange').css('background-color', '');
```

And then reset it using:

```
$('#elementToChange').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Or in a one-liner:

```
$('#elementToChange')
    .css('background-color', '')
    .css('background-color', 'blue');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/HmXXc/186/.

**Original answer**:

*Note: this may be a bad idea, as it will remove any other inline styles*

I would edit the style attribute directly

```
$('.elementToChange').attr('style', 'background-color: blue !important');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/3wemT/1/

Comment: Although this would splat any styles already attached to the element, which could be bad news. I think adding a class is safer.

Comment: This worked - though @RichardTowers was right. It did wipe everything (not a problem, can recreate). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/irpm/bdhpp/2/

The idea is to add the class:

```
$('.elementToChange').addClass('blackBg');
```

Comment: that almost worked... here's a screenshot: http://d.pr/i/qxPl

the top is the external stylesheet. background: blue is what I added with jquery. below is something in my css that worked since it the external css didn't have an !important tag on that. 

advice?

Comment: try to load style.css after ybadge.css in your html. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate !important css by using following steps, either you can use inline-css or Internal css or you can load your own external css after the order of that preloaded css, it will help you to override that css with your custom one.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <!--
    //First Solution
    //PreloaderCSS
    //YourCustomCSS

    //Second Solution
    Internal CSS -->
    </head>
    <body>
<!--
Third solution
//Inline CSS
->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
function replaceBGColorImportant(element,newColor){
    var styles = element.getAttribute('style');
    styles = styles?styles.split(';'):[];
    var newStyles = [];
    styles.map(function(x){
        if (x.split(':')[0] != "background-color")
            newStyles.push(x);
    });
    newStyles.push('background-color:#'+newColor+' !important');
    element.setAttribute('style',newStyles.join(';'));
}
```

Execute as follows:

```
replaceBGColorImportant(document.body,'#009922');
```

Answer (score 0):

Via regular expression:
https://jsfiddle.net/7jj7gq3y/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="elementToChange" style=" background-color: yellow !important; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var setImportantStyle = function(element, attributeName, value) {
    var style = element.attr('style');
    if (style === undefined) return;
    var re = new RegExp(attributeName + ": .* !important;", "g");
    style = style.replace(re, "");
    element.css('cssText', attributeName + ': ' + value + ' !important;' + style);
}
setImportantStyle($('.elementToChange'), 'background-color', 'red');
```